# Как добавить обработчик нажатия на элемент в RecyclerView?

Tags: java, android, recyclerview

Мне нужен горизонтальный лист вью. Стал рыть в интернете, и нашел совет юзать `RecyclerView`. Вроде это новая штука от гугл и тд. Вобщем вставил я его себе в проект. Выводит он все нормально. Написал адаптер и тд. Но как теперь написать обработчик нажатия на айтем??? нашел реализацию этого всего вот тут [*RecyclerView onClick*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24471109/recyclerview-onclick)

Но в итоге получаю такое:

```
mRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(
                new RecyclerItemClickListener(this, new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
                        Toast.makeText(DashboardActivity.this, "dfsdg"+ position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
                    }
                })
        );
```

как мне вместо `"dfsdg"+ position` вывести элемент моего списка??? гугл в очередной раз меня огорчил.

ДОПОЛНИЛ

я добавил метод в адаптер:

```
public User getItem(int position){
    return userList.get(position);
}
```

теперь я имею возможность из вне вытащить свой айтем:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
    Toast.makeText(DashboardActivity.this, ((RecyclerAdapter)mAdapter).getItem(position).getUserInfo().getName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
}
```

Но мне не нравиться то, что я вынужден передавать `mAdapter`. В старом обычном листе можно было обратиться к адаптеру из листвью. Тут этого нет, и как это сделать я не знаю.

Как-то так:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
    adapterView.getAdapter().getItem(i)......
}
```

`adapterView`, а не передавать свой адаптер.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 19):

Для начала, почему же google не реализовала интерфейс `onItemClickListener` в своем новом виджете `RecyclerView`.
Объясняется это тем, что данный интерфейс был весьма не совершенен и, в частности, создавал определенные трудности для обработки кликов на вложенных элементах айтема, также были определенные проблемы с получением [реальной позиции](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24864536) и некоторые другие.
Чтобы избавить себя от подобных проблем google решила доверить реализацию этого сомнительного действия самому программисту ... что же, какие у нас есть варианты.

В первую очередь нужно понять, какого экшена мы чаще всего ожидаем от клика по элементу списка?
Как правило это переход к другой активити со значением кликнутой позиции (каких то связанных с этой позицией данных адаптера и тп).

Реализовать такое простое действие можно просто повешав слушатель прямо в адаптере. Здесь у нас есть доступ к текущей позиции и всем данным адаптера:

```
 @Override
 public void onBindViewHolder( ItemHolder holder, int position) {

            holder.someView.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               // action on click
            }
        });
  }
```

Однако **IP696** в своем комментарии был прав, вешать сложную логику (если такая вдруг потребовалась для обработки клика по айтему) в адаптер не разумно.

Следующий вариант - положить на доводы google и реализовать интерфейс `onItemClicklListener()` самостоятельно.
При такой реализации мы можем передать "на сторону" через интерфейс множество полезных вещей: позицию, данные адаптера по кликнутому айтему, `view` айтема и тд. , но лишаем себя удобной возможности простым способом обрабатывать клики на дочерних элементах, как это можно было сделать в первом варианте и о чем предупреждал нас google. Кроме того, фактически, как правило, нет никакой прямой необходимости обрабатывать клик по айтему на "внешней" стороне. Пример:

```
public class ListAdapterHolder extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ListAdapterHolder.ViewHolder> {

    OnItemClickListener mItemClickListener;

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent , int viewType) {
        ...
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder , int position) {
        ...
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);               
            view.setOnClickListener(this);
             ...
            //здесь можно повесить слушатель и на отдельные виджеты в айтеме
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mItemClickListener != null) {
                mItemClickListener.onItemClick(v, getAdapterPosition());
            }
        }

    }

    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        public void onItemClick(View view , int position);
    }

    public void SetOnItemClickListener(final OnItemClickListener mItemClickListener) {
        this.mItemClickListener = mItemClickListener;
    }
}
```

Наиболее логичным решением ситуации я считаю решение обрабатывать клики в классе-холдере адаптера. Здесь у нас есть простой и прямой доступ ко всем элементам айтема, данные самого адаптера (так как класс вложен в адаптер) для простого добавления\изменения\удаления пунктов списка, кроме того через конструктор можно передать дополнительные данные, кроме, собственно `View`, также логика обработки кликов выведена из адаптера в статический холдер:

```
 public static class ItemHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener  {
    TextView mText;
    Button mButton;
    CardView mCard;

    public ItemHolder(View v) {
        super(v);

        mCard = (CardView) v.findViewById(R.id.item_card);
        mText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.item_text);
        mButton = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.item_button);

        mCard.setOnClickListener(this);
        mButton.setOnClickListener(this);

     }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        int position = getAdapterPosition();
        if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
            switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.card:
                    itemClick(position);
                    break;
                case R.id.button:
                    buttonClick(position);
            }
        }
    }

    private void itemClick(int position){

     //action on item click
    }

    private void buttonClick (int position){

      //action on button click
    }
  }
```

Так же, если клик нужно обработать в активити, то можно просто указать в xml-разметке айтема списка метод обработки клика (`android:onClick`) и реализовать его в активити. [Подробнее](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/612095/177345)

Comment: Вы предлагаете  мне обрабатывать всю логику в адаптере? Это очень умное решение дада

Comment: Ваш ответ весьма некорректный. Если вы трольь то трольте  в трольюшне, я задал вполне понятный вопрос и жду адекватного ответа. вы могли посоветовать мне поискать в google.ru на то пошло. если такой умный дайте ссылку на статью

Comment: @ pavlofff прежде чем меня обвинять, перечитайте мой вопрос, в котором я написал что я получаю позицию за пределами адаптера. и спрашиваю совсем о другом. а именно о том, как мне вытащить сам элемент, а не его позицию

Comment: @IP696 Таким же образом можно получить и `View`, в чем проблема .. исправил ответ

Comment: а в том что вы опять не поняли вопроса. я допишу свой вопрос

Comment: @IP696, Есть ещё вариант с onInterceptTouchEvent в RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener, где-то я видел такую реализацию. А вообще, посмотрите пример в `<sdk>/extras/android/support/samples/Support7Demos/src/com/example/android/supportv7/widget/RecyclerViewActivity.java` - там тоже в адаптере делают (почти). Т. е. авторы считают, что это нормально

Answer (score 4):

Ответ @pavlofff верен. Единственный вопрос где обработать нажатие. В своем проекте мы используем для этого шину событий (Otto by Square). Что то вроде:

```
public class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

  @Inject Bus bus;

  @Override
  public void onBindViewHolder( ItemHolder holder, final int position) {
          holder.view.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
             bus.post(new ItemClickedEvent(getItem(position))); 
          }
      });
  }
}
```

В нужном месте ловим ItemClickedEvent, который содержит в себе модель, ячейка с которой была выбрана. Странно, конечно, что Google не добавила callback как для listview.