# RecyclerView OnClickListener работает только на краях элемента

Tags: java, android

Добавил событие `OnClickListener`.  Использую `Cardview` в `Recyclerview`. Событие работает, только если нажму на грани элемента `Recyclerview`.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="androidhive.info.materialdesign.activity.FriendsFragment">


<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/swipeRefreshLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycleralda"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**carder_new.xml**

```
  <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/carder"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
card_view:cardCornerRadius="7dp"
card_view:cardElevation="2sp"
card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
android:layout_margin="1dp"
android:layout_marginTop="2dip"
android:layout_marginBottom="2dip">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imagePreview"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:text="Lorem ipsum"
            android:id="@+id/titleText"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="Small Text"
            android:id="@+id/dateText"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_weight="2" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

// **Адаптер**

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder>  {
private List<News> news;
private Context mContext;


public RecyclerViewAdapter(List<News> news, Context mContext) {
    this.news = news;
    this.mContext = mContext;

}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.carder_new, parent,false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    News news = this.news.get(position);
    holder.text1.setText(news.getTitle());
    holder.text3.setText(news.getDate());
    Picasso.with(mContext).load(this.news.get(position).getPreviewImage()).resize(150, 120).into
            (holder.imageView);
}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return this.news.size();
}



public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener
{
    public View container;
    public ClipData.Item currentItem;

    private TextView text1;
    private TextView text3;
    private ImageView imageView;

    public ViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        view.setOnClickListener(this);
        text1 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.titleText);
        text3 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.dateText);

        imageView = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imagePreview);

    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Log.e("Axixa", "onClick " + getPosition());
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Код адаптера ? Ваши рзмети ничем не помогут в решении вопроса

Comment: хм. можно чуть подробнее? Где именно пихнуть

Comment: И еще ... getPosition() не рекомендуется к использованию и объявлен устаревшим. Вместо него предлагается `getAdapterPosition()` или `getLayoutPosition()`

Comment: getPosition работает, а вот getAdapterPosition выделяется красным.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для обработки кликов на айтемах списка нужно вешать слушатель кликов на корневой элемент разметки этого айтема, в вашем случае `CardView`:

```
 public ViewHolder(View view) {
    super(view);

    CardView cardView = (CardView) view.findViewById(R.id.carder);
    text1 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.titleText);
    text3 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.dateText);
    imageView = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imagePreview);

   cardView.setOnClickListener(this);
}
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    Log.e("Axixa", "onClick " + getAdapterPosition());
 }
}
```

Так же, при необходимости, можно дополнительно повесить слушатели на вложенные элементы, например `ImageView`, тогда клик на этом элементе будет обрабатываться отдельно от клика по всему айтему.

[Пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/423291/177345)

Comment: Прекрасный ответ!) единственное getPosition работает, а вот getAdapterPosition выделяется красным. Как будто нет такого метода

Comment: @Radzhab Думаю вам стоит обновить SDK до последней версии, включая библиотеки поддержки