# ListView vs RecyclerView

Tags: android, listview, recyclerview

Не так давно начал писать под android и использовал всегда ListView, после чего отдал свой код на проверку и мне сказали что использовать ListView "не камильфо", увы не обосновали почему. Чем они так кординально отличаются и чем RecyclerView лучше ListView?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

RecyclerView новый вид ViewGroup подготовленный для интерпретации одинаковым способом любых view использующих адаптеры . Предполагается, что он будет наследником ListView и GridView. Одна из причин заключается в том, что RecyclerView имеет более расширяемый фрэймворк, тем более что он предоставляет возможность осуществлять как горизонтальную, так и вертикальную компоновку. Используйте  RecyclerView когда у вас есть наборы данных, элементы которого меняются во время выполнения на основе действий пользователя или событий сети.

RecyclerView отличается от своего предшественника Listview в первую очередь из-за следующих особенностей:

1)  **необходимость применения ViewHolder в адаптере** - адаптеры Listview не требуют использования паттерна ViewHolder для повышения производительности. В отличие от этого, исполнение адаптера для RecyclerView требует использования паттерна ViewHolder;

2)  **Настраиваемые слои элементов** - Listview может располагать элементы только в вертикальном линейном порядке и это не может быть изменено. В отличие от Listview ,RecyclerView имеет RecyclerView.Layoutmanager, который позволяет любое размещение элементов, включая горизонтальные списки или сетки в шахматном порядке;

3)  **Легкая анимация элементов** -  Listview не содержит никаких специальных механизмов, посредством которых можно анимировать добавление или удаление элементов. В отличие от Listview ,RecyclerView имеет RecyclerView.ItemAnimator, который позволяет управлять анимацией;

4)  **Устанавливаемый вручную источник данных** - в Listview были адаптеры для различных источников, таких как адаптер массива и CursorAdapter для массивов и базы данных соответственно. В отличие от них RecyclerView.Adapter требует пользовательской реализации доставки данных к адаптеру;

5)  **Ручное декорирование элементов** – ListView  имеет android:divider для легкого разделения элементов в списке. В отличие от Listview ,RecyclerView имеет RecyclerView.ItemDecoration, который обеспечивает более широкие возможности по декорированию разделения;

6)  **Определение нажатия на элемент** - ListView имеет AdapterView.OnItemClickListener интерфейс для связывания событий нажатия с конкретным элементом списка. В отличие от Listview ,RecyclerView поддерживает только RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener  который управляет отдельными событиями нажатия, но не имеет встроенного управления нажатием.

Answer (score 10):

Начнем с того, что виджет `RecyclerView` хотя и визуально похож на `ListView` и вроде бы делает одно и то же, но он не является его прямой заменой и прямое противостояние здесь несколько некорректно. Оба эти виджета имеют свои собственные "ниши" в структуре Android-приложения.

Необходимость в виджете `RecyclerView` появилась по причинам недостаточной приспособленности `ListView` к отображению сложных айтемов с множеством разнотипных `View` и их взаиморасположения в списке. Так же `ListView` имел некоторые технические просчеты, что делало его не столь быстрым и эффективным, как хотелось бы.

В итоге, в виджете `RecyclerView` был полностью переработан алгоритм переиспользования айтемов (с использованием подкласса `Recycler` и некоторых методов по взаимодействию с процессом переиспользования), так же обязательной стала реализация подкласса `ViewHolder`, который кэширует ссылки на `View` айтемов и оптимизирует нагрузку на устройство. Также было реализовано еще [несколько классов-хелперов](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html#nestedclasses) для всевозможных оптимизаций, что должно улучшить производительность. Стоит заметить, что все это так запутало исходный код самого виджета, что разобраться в его работе представляется непростой задачей.

Кроме того были реализованы подклассы визуального оформления, представляющие более простой способ "украсить" этот виджет - `ItemDecoration`, `ItemAnimator`,`LayoutManager` и тп., что способствует комфортному созданию действительно визуально привлекательных списков без всяких "костылей". Также появились методы работы с отдельными айтемами\группой айтемов по вставке, замене и удалению их из списка, против обновления всего списка целиком для `ListView`, что положительно сказывается на отзывчивости и производительности, которые к тому же имеют анимацию действия, что снимает эти хлопоты с разработчика.

Однако не обошлось и без "разочарований". Виджет не имеет ни одного реализованного адаптера для работы с типовыми данными, любой адаптер требуется реализовать самостоятельно, на основе класса-заготовки `RecyclerView.Adapter`, так же не реализованы слушатели на клики в айтемах, их тоже предлагается реализовать самому [по некоторым причинам](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/423291/177345).

В итоге давайте окинем умом изложенное выше и представим, что нам нужен простой примитивный список в одну текстовую строку без всяких "украшений", на подобии `Spinner` (например, выбор города из списка в диалоговом окне или другие типовые задачи такого плана, где спиннер не очень уместен) или пункты бокового меню `NavigationView` и тому подобные задачи отображения списков. Нам не надо ничего удалять или вставлять в такой список, не надо его декорировать или анимировать, а примитивное содержимое в десяток пунктов не требует серьезных оптимизаций.

Совершенно очевидно, что все "навороты" `RecyclerView` в таком применении не только не к месту, но и лишний груз, зато необходимые вещи, как готовый адаптер для вывода простых строк, готовая разметка и слушатель нажатия решительно отсутствуют. В итоге вместо трех строчек для `ListView` реализация простейшего списка займет написание целого класса адаптера и файлов разметки, что несколько огорчает.

Таким образом способы применения этих виджетов лежат в разных плоскостях. `RecyclerView` для "великолепных" сложных списков с многими элементами, анимациями и визуальным оформлением, `ListView` для простых одно- двух- строчных списков (возможно с картинкой) к стандартным наборам данных, как ArrayList, Cursor и тп. где все необходимое уже реализовано средствами самой системы.

Выбор между ними может лежать в той плоскости, что если для `ListView` требуется переопределение адаптера (создание кастомного адаптера), то уже стоит задуматься о `RecyclerView`. Если такой необходимости нет, то и возможности `RecyclerView` будут скорее всего не к месту.

Comment: Согласен с вами. В подобной теме на общем SO я высказывался примерно в том же духе. Добавлю, что ListView в чём-то даже лучше, т.к. не принуждает к использованию ViewHolder. В списке, где все айтемы разные, например, имеют текстовые поля с разными обработчиками маски ввода, это может быть полезно, чтобы не городить ViewHolder'ы, когда достаточно просто создать айтемы и коллбеки. Из преимуществ RecyclerView добавлю адаптер, который в общем случае не зависит от контекста. Т.е. его можно теоретически отвязать от ЖЦ фрагмента и поворота экрана.

Answer (score 2):

1. RecyclerView был создан как усовершенстованная и обновлённая версия виджета для списоков.
2. Гугл рекомендует переходить на RecyclerView по причинам из п.1
3. В RecyclerView множество всяких доп. штук. Например возможность указать адаптеру более подробно как нужно отобразить изменения в данных. Для какого-то конкретного элемента, для группы элементов. ListView мог только сразу все элементы поменять.
4. RecyclerView нельзя использовать без Viewholder, который даёт ряд преимуществ.
5. В RecyclerView сразу встроены анимации для событий добавления/удаления/изменения данных
6. etc