# Изменение разметки фрагмента без его пересоздания

Tags: android, android-layout

Я хочу сделать так, чтобы мой фрагмент мог изменять свою разметку без пересоздания самого себя (т.е. чтобы не было необходимости заново создавать фрагмент и вызывать его конструктор). Я попытался использовать ViewGroup и его методы setView() и removeView() для осуществления замены одной разметки другой, но, кажется, запутался еще больше.

Есть еще один подход решит мою проблему - в разметке Activity сразу создавать два фрагмента для каждой разметки, делая один из них невидимым. Я не думаю, что это эффективный и правильный, с точки зрения эффективности и экономии ресурсов, способ. Хочу узнать ваше мнение о том, как лучше решить подобную задачу

Ниже вы можете увидеть кусок кода, который решает мою задачу, но с пересозданием объекта фрагмента и после нажатия на определенную кнопку на панели действий. Как быть, когда нужно изменить разметку фрагмента без его пересоздания?

```
// Обработка выбора команд меню
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(android.view.MenuItem item) {
    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager(); // Необходим для транзакий фрагментов: при удалении и заменене одного фрагмента другим

    // Выбор в зависимости от идентификатора MenuItem
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.shopping_cart:
            return true; // Событие меню обработано
        case R.id.sort:
            if (fm != null) {
                /*
                Perform the FragmentTransaction to load in the list tab content.
                Using FragmentTransaction#replace will destroy any Fragments
                currently inside R.id.fragment_content and add the new Fragment
                in its place. (с) Google doc
                */
                FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction(); // Начало транзакции
                ( (ViewGroup) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.fragment_menu) ).removeAllViews(); // Удаляет View на экране (сам список)
                ft.remove(this); // Удаляет кнопки на палени действий (TODO: и вместе с ним сам фрагмент?)

                // Замена фрагмента
                if (currentMode == CARD_MODE) {
                    ft.replace(R.id.fragment_menu, new MenuListFragment().setArguments(PLATE_MODE));
                }else {// currentMode == PLATE_MODE
                    ft.replace(R.id.fragment_menu, new MenuListFragment().setArguments(CARD_MODE));

                }
                ft.commit(); // Завершение транзакции
            }
            return true; // Событие меню обработано
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item); //TODO: Разобраться зачем вообще тут нужен супер
}
```

Вот ссылка на полный код проекта, если вам требуется остальной код и разметки: https://github.com/RareScrap/TennoSushi/tree/master

**UPDATE 1** Вот код двух разметок, которые отображают код в виде плиток и в виде обычного списка

fragment_menu_card_list.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:id="@+id/card_main"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     tools:context="com.webtrust.tennosushi.MenuListFragment">

     <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

     <ListView
          android:id="@+id/cardList"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:orientation="horizontal"></ListView>
</FrameLayout>
```

fragment_menu_plates_list.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:id="@+id/plates_main"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     tools:context=".MainActivity">

     <GridView
          android:id="@+id/platesList"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:horizontalSpacing="0dp"
          android:numColumns="2"
          android:verticalSpacing="0sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**UPDATE 2** Код фрагмента

```
package com.webtrust.tennosushi;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ListView;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Простой наследник класса {@link Fragment}.
 * Активити, которые содержат этот фрагмент должно реализовывать
 * интерфейс {@link MenuListFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener}
 * для обработки событий взаимодействия между активностью и фрагментом.
 * Используйте {@link MenuListFragment#newInstance} фабричный метод для
 * создания экземпляра этого фрагмента.
 * @author RareScrap
 */
public class MenuListFragment extends Fragment {
     // Константы, определяющие режим отображения списка
     public static int CARD_MODE = 0;
     public static int PLATE_MODE = 1;

     // Закомментирован, т.к. еще не изучен
     //private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

     // Список объектов MenuItem, представляющих элементы главного меню (категории блюд)
     private List<MenuItem> menuItemList = new ArrayList<>();

     // ArrayAdapter связывает объекты MenuItem с элементами ListView
     private MenuItemArrayAdapter menuItemArrayAdapter;
     private ListView menuItemListListView; // View для вывода информации в виде списка
     private GridView menuItemListGridView; // View для вывода информации в виде плиток

     private int currentMode; // Текущий режим отображения списка

     /**
      * Необходимый пустой публичный конструктор
      */
     public MenuListFragment() {
          setArguments(PLATE_MODE);// режим по умолчанию
     }

     /**
      * Метод-замена для конструктора с параметрами т.к.
      * Google ОЧЕНЬ не рекомендует иметь дополнительные конструкторы
      * во фрагментах
      *
      * @param mode Режим отображения списка
      * @return this Возвращает этот же фрагмент (нужночтобы вызывать сразу после конструктора во FragmentTransaction
      * */
     public android.support.v4.app.Fragment setArguments(int mode) {
          this.currentMode = mode; // режим по умолчанию
          return this;
     }

     /**
      * Используйте этот фабричный метод для создания новых экземпляров
      * этого фрагмента с использованием продоставленных параментров
      * (черт знает где эти "параметры", япросто перевел сгенерированный коммент)
      *
      * @return Новый объект фрагмента {@link MenuListFragment}.
      */
     // TODO: Переменуйте и измените типы и количество параметров (перевод)
     // TODO: разобраться зачем нужен этот метод
     public static MenuListFragment newInstance() {
          MenuListFragment fragment = new MenuListFragment();
          Bundle args = new Bundle();
          fragment.setArguments(args);
          return fragment;
     }

     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

     }

     @Override
     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          setHasOptionsMenu(true); // у фрагмента имеются команды меню

          // Inflate the layout for this fragment
          if (currentMode == CARD_MODE) {
                return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_menu_card_list, container, false);
          }else { // currentMode == PLATE_MODE
                return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_menu_plates_list, container, false);
          }
     }

     @Override
     public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

          // TODO: Лучше ли это место для установки адаптера?
          // ArrayAdapter для связывания weatherList с weatherListView
          menuItemArrayAdapter = new MenuItemArrayAdapter(getActivity(), menuItemList);
          if (currentMode == CARD_MODE) {
                menuItemListListView = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.cardList);
                menuItemListListView.setAdapter(menuItemArrayAdapter);
          }else { // currentMode == PLATE_MODE
                menuItemListGridView = (GridView) getView().findViewById(R.id.platesList);
                menuItemListGridView.setAdapter(menuItemArrayAdapter);
          }

          try {
                URL url = new URL("http://192.168.1.127/index.php");

                GetDataTask getLocalDataTask = new GetDataTask();
                getLocalDataTask.execute(url);
          }
          catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
          }
     }

     @Override
     public void onAttach(Context context) {
          super.onAttach(context);
          /*if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
                mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
          } else {
                throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                          + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
          }*/
     }

     @Override
     public void onDetach() {
          super.onDetach();
          //mListener = null;
     }

     /**
      * Отображение команд меню фрагмента
      * @param menu Меню
      * @param inflater Инфлатер для меню
      */
     @Override
     public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
          super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
          inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_list_menu, menu);
     }

     // Обработка выбора команд меню
     @Override
     public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(android.view.MenuItem item) {
          FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager(); // Необходим для транзакий фрагментов: при удалении и заменене одного фрагмента другим

          // Выбор в зависимости от идентификатора MenuItem
          switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.shopping_cart:
                     return true; // Событие меню обработано
                case R.id.sort:
                     if (fm != null) {
                          /*
                          Perform the FragmentTransaction to load in the list tab content.
                          Using FragmentTransaction#replace will destroy any Fragments
                          currently inside R.id.fragment_content and add the new Fragment
                          in its place. (с) Google doc
                          */
                          FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction(); // Начало транзакции
                          ( (ViewGroup) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.fragment_menu) ).removeAllViews(); // Удаляет View на экране (сам список)
                          ft.remove(this); // Удаляет кнопки на палени действий (TODO: и вместе с ним сам фрагмент?)

                          // Замена фрагмента
                          // TODO: Сделать так, чтобы разметка фрагмента менялась без пересоздания (читай удаления) макета
                          if (currentMode == CARD_MODE) {
                                ft.replace(R.id.fragment_menu, new MenuListFragment().setArguments(PLATE_MODE));
                          }else {// currentMode == PLATE_MODE
                                ft.replace(R.id.fragment_menu, new MenuListFragment().setArguments(CARD_MODE));

                          }
                          ft.commit(); // Завершение транзакции
                     }
                     return true; // Событие меню обработано
          }

          return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item); //TODO: Разобраться зачем вообще тут нужен супер
     }

     /**
      * Этот интерфейс должно быть реализован в активити, которая содержит этот
      * фрагмент, чтобы фрагмен смог взаимодействовать с активити
      * и ,возможно, с другими фрагментами, содержащиеся в этой активити.
      * <p>
      * Подробнее смотрите в Android Training lesson: <a href=
      * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
      * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a>
      * </p>.
      */
     // Закомментирован, т.к. еще не изучен
     /*public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
          // TODO: Update argument type and name
          void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
     }*/

     /* Обращение к REST-совместимому (якобы) веб-сервису за данными блюд и меню
     и сохранение этих данных в локальном файле HTML */

     /**
      * Внутренний класс {@link AsyncTask} для загрузки данных
      * в формате JSON.
      * @author RareScrap
      */
     private class GetDataTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Void, JSONObject> {
          /**
            * Получение данных из сети
            * @param params URL для получения JSON файла
            * @return JSON файл с категориями меню и блюдами в них
            */
          @Override
          protected JSONObject doInBackground(URL... params) {
                HttpURLConnection connection = null;

                try {
                     connection = (HttpURLConnection) params[0].openConnection(); // Для выдачи запроса достаточно открыть объект подключения
                     int response = connection.getResponseCode(); // Получить код ответа от веб-сервера

                     if (response == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                          StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

                          try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()))) {
                                String line;
                                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                                     builder.append(line);
                                }
                          }
                          catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                          }

                          return new JSONObject(builder.toString());
                     }else {
                     }
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                     e.printStackTrace();
                }
                finally {
                     connection.disconnect(); // Закрыть HttpURLConnection
                }

                return null;
          }
          /**
            * Обработка ответа JSON и обновление ListView.
            *
            * @param jsonObject JSON файл полученный после завершения работы doInBackground()
            */
          @Override
          protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject jsonObject) {
                if (jsonObject != null) {
                     convertJSONtoArrayList(jsonObject); // Заполнение weatherList
                     menuItemArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // Связать с ListView

                     // Прокрутить до верха
                     if (currentMode == CARD_MODE) {
                          menuItemListListView.smoothScrollToPosition(0);
                     }else { // currentMode == PLATE_MODE
                          menuItemListGridView.smoothScrollToPosition(0);
                     }
                }
          }
     }

     /**
      * Создание объектов MenuItem на базе JSONObject
      * с последующим их заесением в menuItemList.
      *
      * @param jsonObject Входящий JSON файл
      */
     private void convertJSONtoArrayList(JSONObject jsonObject) {
          menuItemList.clear(); // Стирание старых погодных данных

          try {
                // Получение свойства "list" JSONArray
                JSONArray list = jsonObject.getJSONArray("sushi");

                // Преобразовать каждый элемент списка в объект Weather
                for (int i = 0; i < list.length(); ++i) {
                     JSONObject deash = list.getJSONObject(i); // Данные за день
                     // Получить JSONObject с температурами дня ("temp")
                     String name = deash.getString("name");

                     // Получить JSONObject c описанием и значком ("weather")
                     String picURL = deash.getString("picURL");

                     // Добавить новый объект Weather в weatherList
                     menuItemList.add( new MenuItem(name, picURL));
                }
          }
          catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
          }
     }
}
```

Comment: Хорошо, понял. Но все же почему это неудачное решение? Ведь по сути у меня есть две крайне похожих разметки с полностью одинаковой логикой. И я подумал, что менять разметку фрагмента было бы довольно неплохим решением.

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку на отличный ответ. Что касается логики фрагмента - он просто натягивает на себя список из файла разметки и заполняется его при помощи адаптера, который вынесен в отдельный класс. Весь интерес в том, что адаптер отлично работает с моим фрагментом и его двумя разметками. А разметки представляют из себя два вида одного и того же списка - в "больших картинка" и в "маленьких, как на windows phone картинках-плитках". Именно по этой причине я не хочу создавать еще один фрагмент, т.к. и этот работает с моими разметками весьма неплохо. Никаких полей ввода/вывода в разметках нет

Comment: Если разница только в отображаемом списке, то создавать для этого два отдельных фрагмента действительно лишнее. Добавьте код обоих фрагментов в вопрос. Ссылка на репозиторий имеет малую ценность для переиспользования ответа, так как в будущем может быть утрачена

Comment: Спасибо, буду иметь ввиду. Добавил код разметок, смотрите UPDATE в посте

Comment: Код самих фрагментов (классов, наследованных от класса Fragment), а не разметок.

Comment: Добавил код фрагмента в UPDATE 2

Comment: То есть, если я правильно понял, на самом деле вам нужно просто менять вид списка горизонтальный/карточками? Тогда вам проще использовать один RecyclerView и менять ему LayoutManager (Linear/Grid), кнопку переключения добавлять в экшенбар в самом фрагменте (а не в активити), которая и будет управлять LayoutManager списка этого фрагмента. Тогда подменять разметки/фрагменты вовсе не понадобится

Comment: Спасибо, я изучу RecyclerView и LayoutManager, но я только что нашел ответ на мой вопрос и, мне кажется, что мой способ проще и быстрее. Прошу вас оценить мой подход.

Comment: Лучше использовать Recyclerview с GridLayoutManager. Он может отображать как плиткой так и списком.

Comment: Спасибо за рекомендацию. Но мне казалось, что Recyclerview следует использовать, когда элементы в списке должны подгружаться по мере листания списка

Comment: "элементы в списке должны подгружаться по мере листания списка" - назначение `RecyclerView` точно такое же, как `ListView` и `GridView`. В общем то `RecyclerView` - ["продвинутое" решение](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/604880/177345) второго и третьего.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема решилась использованием LayoutInflater и установкой и обновлением адаптера. Прошу прощения за плохой код, но это решение пришло мне буквально минуту назад после недельного раздумия над проблемой и оно работает!

```
// Обработка выбора команд меню
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(android.view.MenuItem item) {
    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager(); // Необходим для транзакий фрагментов: при удалении и заменене одного фрагмента другим

    // Выбор в зависимости от идентификатора MenuItem
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.shopping_cart:
            return true; // Событие меню обработано
        case R.id.sort:
            if (fm != null) {
                /*
                Perform the FragmentTransaction to load in the list tab content.
                Using FragmentTransaction#replace will destroy any Fragments
                currently inside R.id.fragment_content and add the new Fragment
                in its place. (с) Google doc
                */
                //FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction(); // Начало транзакции
                ( (ViewGroup) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.fragment_menu) ).removeAllViews(); // Удаляет View на экране (сам список)
                //ft.remove(this); // Удаляет кнопки на палени действий (TODO: и вместе с ним сам фрагмент?)

                // Замена фрагмента
                // TODO: Сделать так, чтобы разметка фрагмента менялась без пересоздания (читай удаления) макета
                if (currentMode == CARD_MODE) {
                    currentMode = PLATE_MODE;
                    //ft.replace(R.id.fragment_menu, new MenuListFragment().setArguments(PLATE_MODE));
                    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
                    int a = R.layout.fragment_menu_plates_list; // a и b Созданы, чтобы отслеживать их в отладчике
                    ViewGroup b =  (ViewGroup) this.getView();
                    View view = inflater.inflate(a, b, true); // Помещает разметку "a" как корневой элемент фрагмента
                    menuItemListGridView = (GridView) getView().findViewById(R.id.platesList);
                    menuItemListGridView.setAdapter(menuItemArrayAdapter);
                    menuItemArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // Связать с ListView
                }else {// currentMode == PLATE_MODE
                    currentMode = CARD_MODE;
                    //ft.replace(R.id.fragment_menu, new MenuListFragment().setArguments(CARD_MODE));
                    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
                    int a = R.layout.fragment_menu_card_list;
                    ViewGroup b =  (ViewGroup) this.getView();
                    View view = inflater.inflate(a, b, true);
                    menuItemListListView = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.cardList);
                    menuItemListListView.setAdapter(menuItemArrayAdapter);
                    menuItemArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // Связать с ListView

                }
                //ft.commit(); // Завершение транзакции
            }
            return true; // Событие меню обработано
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item); //TODO: Разобраться зачем вообще тут нужен супер
}
```

Comment: В вопросе вы говорили о оптимизации. Решение с `RecyclerView` будет намного оптимальнее, эффективнее и экономнее, но это ваша программа и, конечно, только вам решать, какой она будет. Я проголосую за ваш ответ за ваше стремление к поиску решения самостоятельно, но учтите сказанное выше.

Comment: Я буду использовать ваш способ как только подробно разберусь что же такое RecyclerView