# В чем заключается разница между ListView и RecyclerView?

Tags: android, listview, recyclerview

В чем заключается разница между `ListView` и `RecyclerView`?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [ListView vs RecyclerView](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/604880/listview-vs-recyclerview)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

RecyclerView был создан в качестве улучшения ListView, так что да, вы можете создать прилагаемый список с контролем ListView, но с использованием RecyclerView проще в нем:

1. Повторное использование клеток при прокрутке вверх / вниз - это возможно при реализации View Holder адаптера ListView, но это необязательная вещь, в то время как в RecycleView это путь по умолчанию записи адаптера.
2. Разъединяет список из контейнера - так что вы можете поместить элементы списка легко во время выполнения в различных контейнерах (LinearLayout, GridLayout) с установкой LayoutManager .
3. Анимирует общие действия списка - Анимации развязаны и делегированы ItemAnimator .
   Существует больше о RecyclerView, но я думаю, что эти точки являются основными.

Таким образом, в заключение, RecyclerView является более гибким управлением для обработки «список данных», который следует модели делегирования проблем и оставляет за собой только одну задачу - переработка предметов.

Comment: возможно стоит добавить что у recyclerview нет choiсemode который был у listview. Почему то об этом все забывают

Answer (score 5):

Основное отличие в том, что `RecyclerView` встроен [паттерн ViewHolder](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/09/android-viewholder-pattern-example.html) что называется из коробки.

В `ListView`, конечно тоже можно встроить паттерн `ViewHolder`, но для этого надо пописать рученьками, а в `RecyclerView` - он уже есть изначально.