# Что лучше среди RecyclerView, ListView, ScrollView и т.п

Tags: java, android

Работая с динамичным добавлением элементов в виде списка понял что есть множество разных типов как RecyclerView, ListView и тому подобному. Уже запутался что с чем использовать. Хочу узнать что на даный момент актульно и удобно в использование и почему, а так же буду рад ссылкам на статьи или темы где можно узнать разницу среди листовых вьюшек.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/604880/listview-vs-recyclerview/605421#605421

Comment: Спасибо то что искал