# Чем сделать список?

Tags: android, android-studio, listview, recyclerview

Для приложения такси хочу во фрагменте сделать список городов, чтобы можно было выбрать в каком городе работать.
Появился вопрос чем. Есть ListView, есть RecyclerView, есть еще варианты разные находил. Подскажите какой самый актуальный и простой, список в один столбец,с возможностью прокрутки и выбора элемента.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/604880/177345 - в вашем случае ListView, по видимому, более чем достаточно, по причинам, изложенным в моем ответе по ссылке

Comment: Один раз разобраться с RecyclerView и забыть об этой проблеме. + Потом в случае необходимости это дело изи расширять. Ну там иконки доьавить или еще что то в пару кликов.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте `RecyclerView`, так как оно лучше работает с памятью.
Список городов будет большой и, если Вы будете использовать `ListView` прокрутку, закончатся ресурсы телефона.

Вот статья, в которой описан простой способ реализовать `RecyclerView` - [Как работать с RecyclerView?](https://devcolibri.com/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81-recyclerview/).

Вам нужно будет создать `ArrayList` городов, адаптер, дата класс и основной класс, который подключит адаптер к `RecyclerView` для вывода элементов.

Comment: Дополню ответ, используйте также Paging Library, чтобы не грузить весь список