# Как правильно создать слушатель в RecyclerView?

Tags: android, recyclerview

До этого момента я писал слушатели в  `RecyclerView` прямо в `onBindViewHolder`. Но где-то видел, что так делать нельзя. А как же тогда? Можно **идеальный** код?

Comment: Идеального кода нет, есть [разумный выбор](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/423291/177345)

Comment: Я читал ваш ответ. Теперь у меня два варианта. Либо по вашему. Тоесть либо получать позицию по `getAdapterPosition()` либо создать метод `bind` и передавать  в него слушатель и позицию. Что лучше, не пойму.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Советую воспользоваться данным решением: [ItemClickSupport](https://github.com/pavel163/ItemClickSupport). Этим решением пользуются многие. Я для себя сделал либу в один класс.

Comment: Вы с Самары?)  спасибо за либу)

Comment: Да, я из Самары

Comment: Круто я тоже) а можно ли с вами пообщаться? На тему карьеры.

Comment: Я думаю, что для такого простого действия можно и свой колбэк прокинуть, всего пара строчек, чем подключать либу.

Comment: В либе один класс, и используются те же колбэки. Просто чуть удобнее. но это мой взгляд.

Comment: Я посмотрел код понял все)) А можно ли ссылку на вконтакте у меня нет скайпа)