# Приложение не подключается к базе данных

Tags: java, android

Пишу приложение под Android. Подключаю к нему Базу данных:

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
private static String DB_NAME = "Database.sqlite";
private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.example.user.project/databases/";
private SQLiteDatabase myDatabase;
private final Context myContext;

public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
    this.myContext = context;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
}

public void checkAndCopyDatabase(){
    boolean dbExist = checkDatabase();
    if (dbExist = true){
        Log.d("Log", "database already exist");
    }else {
        this.getReadableDatabase();
    }
        copyDatabase(myContext);
}

public boolean checkDatabase(){
    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
        if (checkDB != null){
        checkDB.close();
    }
    return checkDB != null ? true : false;
}

public boolean copyDatabase(Context context) {
    try {
        InputStream inputStream = myContext.getAssets().open(DatabaseHelper.DB_NAME);
        String outFileName = DatabaseHelper.DB_PATH + DatabaseHelper.DB_NAME;
        OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
        byte[]buff = new byte[1024];
        int length = 0;
        while ((length = inputStream.read(buff)) > 0) {
            outputStream.write(buff, 0, length);
        }
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();
        Log.w("Log","DB copied");
        return true;
    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}

public void openDatabase(){
    String dbPath = myContext.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME).getPath();
    if (myDatabase != null && myDatabase.isOpen()) {
        return;
    }
    myDatabase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(dbPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
}

public synchronized void close(){
    if (myDatabase != null){
        myDatabase.close();
    }
    super.close();
}

public Cursor QueryData(String query){
    return myDatabase.rawQuery(query,null);
}}
```

Проблема в следующем, до подключения базы приложение запускается нормально на эмуляторе и на телефоне, после подключения БД запускается только на эмуляторе, но не работает на телефоне выбивает ошибку:

```
unknown error (code 14): Could not open database
```

указывает на строку в коде:

```
checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
```

Подскажите пожалуйста в чем может быть проблема.

Comment: Я уже видел данный код в [этом вопросе](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/612345/177345) и он не рабочий в ряде случаев. В [ответе](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/612783/177345) к  вопросу есть класс `DBHelper` с рабочим кодом

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы уверены, что указывается правильный путь к файлу с базой данных?

Я бы рекомендовал использовать метод `ContextWrapper.getDatabasePath`, как это сделано [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10350032/3100967), а не хардкодить константу `DB_PATH`.