# Задержка показа view

Tags: android, listview, android-fragment, cursoradaper

Здравствуйте.Имеется cursorloader в котором получаю из бд тв программу на текущее время.Жму на кнопку и создаю фрагмент с listview в ктором вызываю cursor loaderТ.к. данных много(500 каналов на неделю) данные появляются не сразу а через секунды 3(пустая форма потом данные).Пробовал к фрагменту прикрутить эффект задержки появления.Но все равно не то.Подскажите как показать фрагмент после загрузки данных?

Answer (score 0):

Сначала получите данные, в это время показывайте `ProgressDialog`, например. Поймайте момент, когда данные из БД будут получены полностью и только потом создавайте фрагмент и передавайте ему данные.

Или вы можете обернуть `ListView` и `ProgressBar` в `FrameLayout`. Пока данные считываются под списком будет крутиться кружок. Не забудьте скрывать его при загрузке данных

Comment: Так у меня несколько фрагментов поэтому я при во фрагменте oncreate запускаю cursorloader.как отловить?

Comment: Переопределите метод `onLoadFinished`

Comment: Т.е. такое явление это нормально?у меня еще есть поиск каналов в бд так при вводе есть задержка видел программы у них тоже из бд посмотрел код ничего особенного так у гих почему то без задержки.может есть какой то фокус?

Comment: Я с базой данной так масштабно не работал. Ответил на вопрос чисто "решением из гугла" и вовсе не из собственного опыта. Я думаю надо к БД обращаться через `AsyncTask`, а вообще я вроде где-то видел или слышал какую-то ОРМ (ORM)

Comment: AsyncTask проблемы думаю не решит.

Comment: Старая но вроде надо почитать https://m.habrahabr.ru/post/125883/

Comment: Читал это не то

Comment: @Ivan а зачем вам поиск делать в самом бд? Не легче поиск делать уже в самом адаптере, когда список наполнился?

Comment: Гугл говорит что в адаптере cursoradapter такое не прокатит в отличие от baseadapter например.емли знаете способ скажите

Comment: @Ivan а у вас список пополняется постоянно динамически, чтобы использовать cursorAdapter? Не легче сделать объект вашего канала и указать в объекте массив `String` передач. В том же `CursorLoader` при `onLoadFinished` заполнить массив с вашим объектом и передать его `BaseAdapter` так думаю будет легче идти процесс.

Comment: Хотел я то же создать baseadapter и например map《string list《program》》да че то при переборе тратится на заполнение много ресурсов.или вы как то по другому имели ввиду?

Comment: @Ivan да, сейчас покажу в ответе

Comment: @Ivan я правильно вас понял, что вы хотите получить программу передач зайдя на определенный канал? Т.е. вы открываете в фрагменте какой то определенный канал и появляется программа? И вы в базе ищете программу по ID канала?

Comment: Я открываю фрагмент источник тв программ.допустим их 2.я жму на любой и загружаю список всех каналов в этом источнике на текущее время в новом фрагменте.там же емть окно для поиска которое и пенсионерит.промто есть программы эта же программа тв а поиск без тормозов.

Comment: @Ivan т.е. у вас есть список каналов, и у каждого канала есть программа передач и поиск осуществляется и по каналам и по программе передач?

Comment: В бд есть таблица программа с полями имя канала программы описание начало конец и т.д.сейчас у меня поиск только по имени еще буду делать и по тередачи.

Comment: @Ivan `CursorLoader` уже работает в асинхронном потоке и `AsyncTask` будет совершенно лишним, вы правы.. Фильтр [по БД с `CursorLoader`](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/612783/177345), может поможет. Вообще нужен код, как вы запросы делаете и тд. Выборка 500 записей не может вешать данные на 3 секунды.

Comment: Задержка та есть.Просто там запрос сложный из нескольких таблиц

Answer (score 0):

Например создаете класс `itemTv`

```
public class itemTv {

    private int _id;
    private String titleTv;
    private String programsTv;

    public itemTv(int _id, String titleTv, String programsTv){
        super();
        this._id = _id;
        this.titleTv = titleTv;
        this.programsTv = programsTv;
    }

    public int get_id() {
        return _id;
    }

    public String getTitleTv() {
        return titleTv;
    }

    public String getProgramsTv() {
        return programsTv;
    }
}
```

Потом при `onLoadFinished`:

```
@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
    if (data != null && data.moveToFirst()){
        List<itemTv> programs = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i=0; i < data.getCount(); i++){
            programs.add(new itemTv(
                id,
                title,
                programs
            ));
        }

        //Я честно говоря не понял какая у вас схема база данных и как вы обращаетесь к базе чтобы получить каналы, а также получить программу передач отдельного канала, но думаю вы схему поняли, определяете Item вашего канала как вы желаете, дальше делаете массив List<с вашим item> и заполняете его в onLoadFinished и отправляете в BaseAdapter где вы требуете List<с вашим item>
    }
}
```

Comment: А так память жрать не будет?в таблице программа емть поле name и в таблице channel есть name вот из channel join да where pr.name=ch.name значит канал наш а так же та еще проверка на текущее время.в общем проверок полно.

Comment: @Ivan память жрать не будет, ибо вы уже все подгрузили, здесь просто ваш список обрабатывается, да и легче уже потом этим списком управлять, поиск и т.д. Тогда вам нужно 2 `item`а сделать, 1 просто для меню, т.е. отображения списка каналов, другой уже список программ для канала.

Comment: В epg прогоамме не сильны?

Comment: Каким образом дополнительная промежуточная перегонка в коллекцию после выборки из БД ускорит отображение данных?

Comment: @pavlofff А что ускорит?

Comment: @Ivan не имея вашего кода могу сказать, что ускорит оптимизация запроса, наверное или что то другое, может быть ..