# Приложение вылетает при прокрутке ExpandableListView

Tags: android

Есть кастомный ExpandableListView, куда выводятся данные из БД, если в раскрывающемся списке больше данных, чем отображается на экране и начинаю прокручивать список, то приложение вылетает на телефоне, на эмуляторе не заметила такого что-то. Почему такое может происходить?

Вот стектрейс

```
Process: test.myapp, PID: 12547
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 4905612 byte allocation with 961968 free bytes and 939KB until OOM
at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:856)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:675)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:2228)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:4211)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:4085)
at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:2005)
at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:1987)
at android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:464)
at android.widget.ImageView.resolveUri(ImageView.java:827)
at android.widget.ImageView.setImageResource(ImageView.java:434)
at de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView.setImageResource(CircleImageView.java:290)
at test.myapp.ExpListAdapter.bindChildView(ExpListAdapter.java:87)
at android.widget.CursorTreeAdapter.getChildView(CursorTreeAdapter.java:251)
at android.widget.ExpandableListConnector.getView(ExpandableListConnector.java:451)
at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2934)
at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1945)
at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:719)
at android.widget.ListView.fillSpecific(ListView.java:1391)
at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1712)
at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2728)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17972)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5814)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1080)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17972)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5814)
at android.support.design.widget.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.layoutChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:131)
at android.support.design.widget.ViewOffsetBehavior.onLayoutChild(ViewOffsetBehavior.java:42)
at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onLayoutChild(AppBarLayout.java:1375)
at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayout(CoordinatorLayout.java:870)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17972)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5814)
at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:1193)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17972)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5814)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:344)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:281)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17972)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5814)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1742)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1585)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1494)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17972)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5814)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:344)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:281)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17972)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5814)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1742)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1585)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1494)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17972)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5814)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:344)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:281)
at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onLayout(PhoneWindow.java:3129)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17972)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5
```

Вот сам проблемный код

```
public class ExpListAdapter extends SimpleCursorTreeAdapter {

    DBHeler dbHeler;
    private int layout;

    public ExpListAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor, int groupLayout,
                          String[] groupFrom, int[] groupTo, int childLayout,
                          String[] childFrom, int[] childTo) {
        super(context, cursor, groupLayout, groupFrom, groupTo,
                childLayout, childFrom, childTo);
        dbHeler = new DBHeler(context);
        this.layout = childLayout;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder {
        public CircleImageView imgView;
        public TextView txtName;
        public TextView txtHistory;
        public ImageButton btnFavorite;

        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            imgView = (CircleImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgView);
            txtName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtName);
            txtHistory = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtHistory);
            btnFavorite = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.btnFavorite);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Cursor getChildrenCursor(Cursor groupCursor) {
        int idColumn = groupCursor.getColumnIndex(Contract.Entry._ID);
        return dbHeler.getBluda(groupCursor.getInt(idColumn));
    }

    @Override
    public View newChildView(Context context, Cursor cursor, boolean isLastChild, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = inflater.inflate(layout, parent, false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
        view.setTag(viewHolder);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    protected void bindChildView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor, boolean isLastChild) {

        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();

        int _ID = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(Contract.Entry._ID));
        String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Contract.Entry.COLUMN_NAME));
        String history = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Contract.Entry.COLUMN_history));
        String image = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Contract.Entry.COLUMN_IMAGE));
        String favorite = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Contract.Entry.COLUMN_FAVORITE));

        holder.txtName.setText(name);
        holder.txtHistory.setText(history);

        holder.btnFavorite.setFocusable(false);

        if (favorite.equals("0")) {
            holder.btnFavorite.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_star_outline_black);
        } else {
            holder.btnFavorite.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_star_yellow);
        }

        Resources resources = context.getResources();
        int resId = resources.getIdentifier(image, "raw", context.getPackageName());
        holder.imgView.setImageResource(resId);

        holder.btnFavorite.setTag(new Dost(_ID, name, history, resId, favorite));
    }
}
```

Я переделала приложение как тут [Фильтрация данных ListView при использовании CursorLoader](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/612345/%D0%A4%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-listview-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-cursorloader). Иногда заметила такое, когда раскрываю первую группу, где больше всего вложенных айтемов и начинаю скроллить, то приложение закрывается, при этом в стектрейсе ничего не выводится похожее на ошибку, а если раскрыть вторую группу допустим, а потом первую и начать скроллить вылезла ошибка которую выше описала

Comment: ошибка значит, что у вас вылет по переполнению памяти при загрузке изображений. Их размер слишком большой для тестируемого устройства

Comment: Дело в том, что при загрузке на экран происходит их обработка (масштабирование и пр.) и при достаточном количестве изображений на эти операции может не хватать памяти, что мы и наблюдаем. Так же в плане размера имеет значение и их геометрические размеры в пикселях, а не только размер файла. В общем нужно оптимизировать по этому параметру, возможно для начала попробовать использовать что то вроде Picasso или Glide

Comment: Нормально. изображения рекомендуется использовать в формате .png - он более оптимизирован, а сами эти изображения в res/raw лучше не хранить, для них есть res/drawable

Comment: Стектрейс указывает на нехватку памяти при обработке графических файлов, а не загрузки данных.

Comment: вроде решилось. Сделала 100 на 100 размер картинок)