# Как лучше обновить список после добавления данных в БД?

Tags: android, sql, recyclerview.adapter

Есть БД. Есть список, который выводит все записи из нее. В этой же активности есть возможность добавления данных в БД. Как лучше сделать автообновление списка? Использую `RecyclerView`. Передаю `ArrayList<String>`. Вариантов, как я понял, несколько:

1) Добавлять данные в БД и те же данные в `ArrayList` и вызывать `notifyDataSetChanged`.

2) Добавлять данные в БД, снова брать все данные, создавать адаптер и присваивать его списку

3) Передавать курсор в адаптер. Просто добавлять данные в БД и вызывать `requery` у курсора (надо ли?)

Какой вариант самый лучший? Какие нет? Почему? Если ли еще способы?

Comment: третий вариант с [CursorAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html) - полученный курсор передается сразу в адаптер. Этот адаптер имеет атрибут в параметрах - автообновление списка при изменении данных в курсоре (третий аргумент конструктора типа boolean)/ Второй вариант - `CursorLoader` и метод `restart()`. Про всякие `ArrayList` и прочие извращения с перегонкой из курсора в какие о промежуточные списки можете сразу забыть - это бессмысленно и беспощадно.

Comment: @pavlofff, спасибо, вы мне давно со списками помогаете :) теперь понял, передача курсора. Про `CursorAdapter` не понял, его можно использовать с `RecyclerView`?

Comment: А .. нет. вы же про `RecyclerView`... для него вообще нет готовых адаптеров. Ну, можно сделать свой, на основе класса для `ListView`, хотя я бы рекомендовал сделать простой адаптер с данными из переданного курсора и работать с `CursorLoader` - это решит множество не очевидных проблем в дальнейшем, хотя сначала и кажется более сложным. Завтра, если время будет нормальный ответ напишу. Пока можете пример посмотреть с [CursorLoader](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/612783/177345), правда он с ListView, но для понимания это не принципиально. Фильтрация здесь - обновление списка фактически

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Берите исходники `CursorRecyclerViewAdapter` - [тынц](https://gist.github.com/skyfishjy/443b7448f59be978bc59)

В поставке из коробки для `RecyclerView` нет адаптера над `Cursor`, что и исправляет данный код.

Работает отлично - проверял.