# Проблема с закрытием курсора

Tags: java, android, sqlite, cursor

```
Cursor c = db.rawQuery("select _id, first,second from mainTable", null);
ClientCursorAdapter adapter = new ClientCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.listview, c, 0 );
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
//c.close();
```

После этого в `ListView` передается курсор и на нем отображается содержимое курсора, но, если я закрываю курсор в конце, то в приложении выходит ошибка - курсором же все еще пользуется `ListView`. А если оставляю курсор открытым, то есть убираю `c.close()`, то все нормально - ошибок нету.

Оставлять курсор открытым – это же неправильно. Что тут можно придумать?

Comment: `то в приложении выходит ошибка` – какая именно? Покажите стек-трейс.

Answer (score 2):

Для работы с курсором в Android есть замечательный класс [`CursorLoader`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/CursorLoader.html), который самостоятельно следит за его жизненным циклом и актуальным состоянием (самостоятельно закрывает курсор, когда им больше не пользуются и обновляет его при изменении данных), так же решает проблемы изменения конфигурации (поворота), работает в асинхронном режиме и другие преимущества.

[Официальная документация](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html?hl=ru)

[Пример использования](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/612783/177345) в адаптере с двумя типами данных и фильтром

Answer (score 0):

Добавлю свои *пять копеек*:

целиком поддерживая [пост @pavloff](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/655033/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0/655114#655114) - вынужден признать, что бывают случаи, когда не все можно отработать в рамках `CursorLoader`

В таких случаях, когда трудно лоцировать когда нужно закрывать `Cursor`'ы надо их закрывать в методе `onDestroy()` активити. Если речь идет о диалоге, то закрывать их в `onDismiss()`. Для фрагментов - лучшее место `onDestroyView()`