# Вывод из бд в строковый массив

Tags: java, android

Имеется база данных содержащая столбец с названиями. Каким образом можно вывести данные из БД в массив, а потом из этого массива заполнить `ListView`?

Comment: для решения вашей задачи (заполнение списка данными из БД) вам не нужно делать строковый массив. Вам нужно узнать о CursorAdapter и работать с данными БД напрямую

Comment: У вас случайно нету примера использования cursoradapter?

Comment: [Пример 1](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/simplecursoradapter.php), [Пример2](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/111-urok-37), [больше примеров](http://www.yandex.ru/yandsearch?text=listview%20simplecursoradapter)/ Это простейшие примеры, в реальном приложении строго рекомендуется работать с `Cursor` через [`CursorLoader`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/655114/177345)

Comment: Посмотри, может тебе поможет в решении!
[Глянь](https://androidjson.com/multiple-json-parsing-data-recyclerview/)