# Как скопировать sqlite базу данных из assets Android 4.0+?

Tags: android, sqlite, assets

Есть приложение, в папку Assets которого я поместил готовую SQLite базу данных с именем `as_database.db`. Её, кстати, ранее создало другое Android приложение, и БД 1оо% рабочая.

В Google нашел массу примеров, но после них всегда падает приложение. Падает в момент обращения к БД через Cursor.

В LogCat ничего не падает.

Есть рабочий код у кого-то с пояснением работы под мой случай ?

Comment: Без лога ошибки сложно... Вряд ли найдётся кто-то кто такое видел. Попробуйте таки как-то лог получить.

Comment: В [этом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/612783/177345) пример копирования  базы данных SQLite, из assets/, а так же взаимодействие с ней из приложения (код оттестированный и 100% рабочий)

Comment: @pavlofff Ничего не работает! Скопировал DBHeler, запустил приложение. Ловлю ошибку - невозможно открыть БД.

Comment: БД копирвется, норм работает, но ошибка в лог все равно вылетает E/SQLiteDatabase: Failed to open database '/data/data/com.myapp/databases/as_database.db'.
                                     android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database