# CursorAdapter для RecyclerView

Tags: android, cursoradaper

Для вывода списка из БД в RecyclerView у меня получились такие классы.

Делала адаптер по типу https://gist.github.com/skyfishjy/443b7448f59be978bc59

Я не поняла что писать в

```
public static BludaList fromCursor(Cursor cursor) {
    //TODO return your MyListItem from cursor.
  }
```

И как в MainActivity вывести потом список? Там не приведен пример класса MainActivity.

Вот сами классы

Contract.java

```
public final class Contract {
    private Contract() {}

    public static final String DB_NAME = "bluda.db";
    public static final int DB_VERSION = 1;

    public static abstract class Bluda implements BaseColumns {
        public static final String TAB_BLUDA = "bluda";

        public final static String _ID = BaseColumns._ID;
        public static final String COL_BLUDO = "bludo";
        public static final String COL_RECEPT = "recept";
        public static final String COL_LIKE = "like";
    }
}
```

DBHelper.java

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static String DB_PATH;
    public SQLiteDatabase database;
    private Context myContext;

    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, Contract.DB_NAME, null, Contract.DB_VERSION);
        this.myContext = context;
        try {
            DB_PATH = myContext.getDatabasePath(Contract.DB_NAME).toString();
            createDataBase();
            openDataBase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public Cursor getRusWords() {
        return database.query(Contract.Bluda.TAB_BLUDA,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null, null, null);
    }



    public void createDataBase() throws IOException {

        boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

        if (!dbExist) {
            this.getReadableDatabase();
            try {
                copyDataBase();
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                throw new Error("Error copying database");
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean checkDataBase(){
        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
        try {

            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DB_PATH, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
        }
        catch (SQLiteException e) {
        }
        if (checkDB != null) {
            checkDB.close();
        }
        return checkDB != null;
    }

    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {
        InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(Contract.DB_NAME);

        String outFileName = DB_PATH;

        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();
    }

    public void openDataBase() throws SQLException {
        database = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DB_PATH, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {
        if(database != null)
            database.close();
        super.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }
}
```

CursorRecyclerViewAdapter.java

```
public abstract class CursorRecyclerViewAdapter<VH extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder> extends RecyclerView.Adapter<VH> {

    private Context mContext;

    private Cursor mCursor;

    private boolean mDataValid;

    private int mRowIdColumn;

    private DataSetObserver mDataSetObserver;

    public CursorRecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        mContext = context;
        mCursor = cursor;
        mDataValid = cursor != null;
        mRowIdColumn = mDataValid ? mCursor.getColumnIndex("_id") : -1;
        mDataSetObserver = new NotifyingDataSetObserver();
        if (mCursor != null) {
            mCursor.registerDataSetObserver(mDataSetObserver);
        }
    }

    public Cursor getCursor() {
        return mCursor;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if (mDataValid && mCursor != null) {
            return mCursor.getCount();
        }
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        if (mDataValid && mCursor != null && mCursor.moveToPosition(position)) {
            return mCursor.getLong(mRowIdColumn);
        }
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void setHasStableIds(boolean hasStableIds) {
        super.setHasStableIds(true);
    }

    public abstract void onBindViewHolder(VH viewHolder, Cursor cursor);

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(VH viewHolder, int position) {
        if (!mDataValid) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("this should only be called when the cursor is valid");
        }
        if (!mCursor.moveToPosition(position)) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("couldn't move cursor to position " + position);
        }
        onBindViewHolder(viewHolder, mCursor);
    }

    public void changeCursor(Cursor cursor) {
        Cursor old = swapCursor(cursor);
        if (old != null) {
            old.close();
        }
    }

    public Cursor swapCursor(Cursor newCursor) {
        if (newCursor == mCursor) {
            return null;
        }
        final Cursor oldCursor = mCursor;
        if (oldCursor != null && mDataSetObserver != null) {
            oldCursor.unregisterDataSetObserver(mDataSetObserver);
        }
        mCursor = newCursor;
        if (mCursor != null) {
            if (mDataSetObserver != null) {
                mCursor.registerDataSetObserver(mDataSetObserver);
            }
            mRowIdColumn = newCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_id");
            mDataValid = true;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        } else {
            mRowIdColumn = -1;
            mDataValid = false;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        return oldCursor;
    }

    private class NotifyingDataSetObserver extends DataSetObserver {
        @Override
        public void onChanged() {
            super.onChanged();
            mDataValid = true;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onInvalidated() {
            super.onInvalidated();
            mDataValid = false;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

BludaList.java

```
public class BludaList {
    long id;
    String bludo;
    String recept;
    int like;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getBludo() {
        return bludo;
    }

    public void setBludo(String bludo) {
        this.bludo = bludo;
    }

    public String getRecept() {
        return recept;
    }

    public void setRecept(String recept) {
        this.recept = recept;
    }

    public int getLike() {
        return like;
    }

    public void setLike(int like) {
        this.like = like;
    }
}
```

BludaAdapter.java

```
public class BludaAdapter extends CursorRecyclerViewAdapter<BludaAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    public BludaAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor){
        super(context,cursor);
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView mTextView;
        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            mTextView = view.findViewById(R.id.text);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(itemView);
        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, Cursor cursor) {
        BludaList bludaList = BludaList.fromCursor(cursor);
        viewHolder.mTextView.setText(bludaList.getBludo());
    }
}
```

Comment: возьмите лучше [этот адаптер](https://github.com/androidessence/RecyclerViewCursorAdapter/) - он гораздо проще. Так же есть [пример использования](https://github.com/androidessence/RecyclerViewCursorAdapter/tree/master/sample/src/main)

Comment: Я смотрела этот пример и не поняла толком ничего. ContentProvider и т.д.

Comment: Или может быть есть исходник который работает с готовой базой из assets

Comment: Использовать `СontentProvider` совсем не обязательно. Например смотрите [этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/612783/177345)/ Там в классе `MainActivity` реализован собственный класс (вложенный) `MyCursorLoader`, который принимает обычный курсор, а не контентпровайдер. Так же в этом примере используется база из Assets. Пример для `ListView`, но с таким же успехом вы можете использовать адаптер по ссылке выше для `RecyclerView`  Использовать же `CursorLoader` настоятельно рекомендуется при работе с SQLite в Android