# Как организовать фильтрацию данных из БД в Android приложении?

Tags: java, android, база-данных, мобильная-разработка, мобильные-приложения

Здравствуйте. Есть приложение - каталог одежды. Есть заполненная база данных. Как мне организовать взаимодействие приложения с БД, путем фильтрации выбранных пользователем критериев из приложения. Т.е. пользователь выбирает определенные пункты в меню, а на выходе ему выдается выборка объектов из БД, которая подходит по его параметрам. Я новичок в этом деле, если можно - простым языком. Спасибо. 
[image: база данных]

Comment: вопорс может содержать только одну проблему. Если у вас несколько проблем - создайте несколько вопросов. Из этого вопроса вторую часть удалите (кнопка "править" под вопросом) и создайте новый вопрос. Так же вопрос должен содержать какие то попытки реализации задуманного, чтобы проблема имела прикладной (а не общий) характер.  Как здесь [задавать вопросы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), чтобы получить полезный ответ. Пример [фильтра по БД](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/612783/177345)

Comment: Для поиска по названию лучше использовать FTS таблицу с _id и name. Хранить картинки в БД слишком накладно сказывается на производительности. Для оффлайна лучше хранить картинки в спец директории, либо использовать кэш.

Comment: Фильтр будет производиться не по названиям, а по числам 1 или 0. Про хранение изображений, вы имели в иду LruCashe/DiskLruCash?