# Как организовать взаимодействие приложения и БД sqlite?

Tags: android, sqlite, activity, mobile-development

Здравствуйте. В приложении есть activity, в котором задается вопрос и выбирается один ответ, путем нажатия на кнопку.

```
    package com.example.eugene.myapplication;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
    View.OnClickListener {

    Button green;
    Button red;
    Button blue;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    green = findViewById(R.id.green);
    red = findViewById(R.id.red);
    blue = findViewById(R.id.blue);

    green.setOnClickListener(this);
    red.setOnClickListener(this);
    blue.setOnClickListener(this);
     }

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.green:
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, one.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        case R.id.red:
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, two.class);
            startActivity(intent1);
            break;
        case R.id.blue:
            Intent intent2 = new Intent(this, three.class);
            startActivity(intent2);
            break;
        default:
            break;
       }
     }
   }
```

При нажатию на кнопку, нас перекидывает на новый Activity:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.eugene.myapplication.MainActivity">

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/Head"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Выберите цвет!">
    </TextView>

    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/green"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:text="Зеленый">
    </Button>
    <Button
    android:id="@+id/red"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:text="Красный">
    </Button>
    <Button
    android:id="@+id/blue"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:text="Синий">
    </Button>
    </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Есть база данных с набором определенных значений:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Зеленый цвет = 1. Красный = 2. Синий = 3.
Базу добавил в папку assets  в директории приложения.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Собственно вопрос. Подскажите как организовать взаимодействия моего activity с БД, чтобы при нажатии допустим кнопки "зеленый", мне фильтровало БД и выдавало только строки с этим параметром. А если в последствии будет второе activity, но уже с другим вопросом, как связать два этих поиска чтобы уже по результату сортировки по двум activity, выдавала мне оставшиеся в процессе отсеивания результаты. Спасибо

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как организовать фильтрацию данных из БД в Android приложении?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/793774/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b3%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%84%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8e-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%91%d0%94-%d0%b2-android-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8)

Comment: Логика фильтрации не совсем ясна. Вы хотите нажать на "зеленый" и появится только зеленый, потом нажать на "красный" и появится и красный и зеленый, а как в такой логике после нажатий на красный и зеленый получить только синий? Возможно вам нужна группа чекбоксов, в которых отмечаешь нужные цвета и потом их выводишь?

Comment: Не так объяснил. В первом окне - выбор цвета, во втором - допустим размер, в третьем - вкус и т.д.