# не видит таблицу в методе query

Tags: android, sqlite, запрос

При попытке реализовать метод `query` выводит ошибку:

> "no such table: ShopDB2table (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT *
>   FROM ShopDB2table".

Вот код для метода:

```
    private GoodsCursorWrapper queryGoods(String whereClause, String[] whereArgs) {
        Cursor cursor = mSQLiteDatabase.query(
                "ShopDB2table",
                null,
                whereClause,
                whereArgs,
                null,
                null,
                null
        );
        return new GoodsCursorWrapper(cursor);
    }
```

Код для курсор-Раппера .

```
     public class GoodsCursorWrapper extends CursorWrapper {

        public GoodsCursorWrapper(Cursor cursor) {
            super(cursor);
        }

        public Goods getGoods() {

            int id = getInt(getColumnIndex(COLUMN_ID));
            String titleOfGoods = getString(getColumnIndex(TITLE_OF_GOODS));
            String price = getString(getColumnIndex(PRICE));

            Goods goods = new Goods();

            goods.setID(id);
            goods.setTitleGoods(titleOfGoods);
            goods.setPrice(price);

            return goods;
        }
    }
```

Код, которым в приложение вставляется существующая база и ее таблица

```
public class ShopBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private static final int VERSION = 1;
private static String DB_PATH = null;
private final Context myContext;

public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "databasesShopDB2.db";
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "ShopDB2table";

static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
static final String TITLE_OF_GOODS = "TitleOfGoods2";
static final String PRICE = "Price2";

private SQLiteDatabase mSQLiteDatabase;

public ShopBaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, VERSION);
    this.myContext = context;
    this.DB_PATH = context.getApplicationInfo().dataDir + "/databases/";
    try {
        createDataBase();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    openDataBase();

}

public void createDataBase() throws IOException {
    boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

    if (dbExist) {
    } else {
        this.getReadableDatabase();

        try {
            copyDataBase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new Error("Error copying database");
        }
    }

}

private boolean checkDataBase() {

        File myPath = new File (DB_PATH + DATABASE_NAME);

    return myPath.exists();
}



private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {

    InputStream goodsInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DATABASE_NAME);

    String outFileName = DB_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;

    OutputStream goodsOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = goodsInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        goodsOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }

    goodsOutput.flush();
    goodsOutput.close();
    goodsInput.close();

}

public void openDataBase() throws SQLException {

    String bdPath = DB_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
    mSQLiteDatabase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(bdPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY);
}

public synchronized void close() {

    if (mSQLiteDatabase != null)
        mSQLiteDatabase.close();
    super.close();

}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersuin) {

}}
```

Comment: А название базы правильное?

Answer (score 2):

База создаётся в любом случае - если копирование не удалось (а это так и есть), то хелпер создаёт её сам (пустую) по первой просьбе открыть базу.
У Вас нет сепаратора (`/`) между папкой и файлом: `DB_PATH + DATABASE_NAME` - если оно и пишется, то не туда.
Во-вторых, вызов `this.getReadableDatabase();` - создаёт (если не существует) и открывает базу - не нужно этого делать перед копированием.
В-третьих, хардкодный путь к файлу базы может не на всех устройствах оказаться правильным. Папку для хранения баз можно спросить у контекста, если не изменяет память.

Comment: Не совсем понял - Вы предлагаете сепаратор поставить так:   
 DB_PATH /  DATABASE_NAME . ?                                 И не подскажете, как запросить папку для хранения у контекста?

Comment: Похоже у Вас код из [этого ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/612783/11515), только изменён в некоторых местах неправильно - сравните с оригиналом и найдёте свои ошибки.

Comment: Я исправил ошибку в коде - в том плане, что добавил в конструктор ShopBaseHelper реализацию методов createDataBase() и openDataBase(). Теперь метод query может запрашивать данные в созданной базе и ошибка no such table: ShopDB2table не возникает.  НО: сохранилась старая ошибка - база так и не создается (не копируется). В результате query обращается к пустой базе, которая создается по умолчанию. Приложение теперь не "вылает" - но выводит, как и ожидалось, пустой экран вместо списка значений. А поскольку лог пустой, то я не понимаю, где найти ошибку... Почему база не вставляется...

Comment: Тогда обновите вопрос актуальным кодом и пояснением что теперь не так, чтобы повысить шансы получить решение проблемы.

Comment: Проблема решена. Честно, до конца не понимаю за счет чего. Возможно дело было не в коде, а "ломанном" файле базы, который я хотел подгрузить...   Так или иначе, выкладываю рабочий код