# Room. Поиск. Вывод всех данных, если editText пустая строка

Tags: android

При нажатии на кнопку поиска, открывается фрагмент, где сверху editText и под ним recyclerView. Все работает, но при открытии фрагмента он пустой, а нужно чтоб сначала выводились все элементы списка, которые при наборе заголовка будут динамически фильтроваться.

dataDao

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM Data WHERE title LIKE :search")
List<Data> getAllSearch(String search);
```

ViewModel

```
    public class DataViewModelSearch extends AndroidViewModel {

   public MutableLiveData<List<Data>> searchData = new MutableLiveData<>();

    private DataRepository repository;

    public DataViewModelSearch(@NonNull Application application) {
        super(application);
        repository = new DataRepository(application);
    }

    public void refresh(String searchText) {
        String formattedSearchText = "%" + searchText + "%";
        new GetSearchDataTask().execute(formattedSearchText);
    }

    @SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
    private class GetSearchDataTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<Data>> {

        @Override
        protected List<Data> doInBackground(String... params) {
           return repository.getAllSearch(params[0]);
       }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<Data> data) {
            super.onPostExecute(data);
            searchData.setValue(data); 
        }
    }
}
```

fragment

```
 dataListViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(DataListViewModel.class);
    dataListViewModel.searchData.observe(this, new Observer<List<Data>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(List<Data> data) {
            adapter.setData(data);
        }
    });

    etFilter.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            dataListViewModel.refresh(charSequence.toString());

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

        }
    });
```

код фрагмента, где расположена кнопка

```
btnSearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        SearchFragment searchFragment = new SearchFragment();
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        if (fragmentManager != null) {
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.content_frame, 
searchFragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();

         }
     }
 });
```

Comment: `SELECT * FROM Data WHERE title LIKE :search + "%"` - процент задает нечеткий поиск - все строки, начинающиеся со строки `search` (при пустой строке search это вся выборка), но я не уверен, что в Room именно так можно добавить символ к передающейся в запрос строке. Еще по [похожему вопросу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/612783/177345)

Comment: А если при создании `DataViewModelSearch` сделать `refresh` с пустой строкой? Например, прямо в конструкторе или во фрагменте после создания экземпляра `dataListViewModel`. Просто у вас запрос к БД выполняется только после ввода фильтра

Comment: @VasilBaymurzin Помогло во фрагменте сделать `dataListViewModel.refresh("");` Спасибо!

Comment: @Agatha лучше это сделать в конструкторе ViewModel, потому что когда вы повернете экран, то ваш рефреш выполниться второй раз, потому что фрагмент пересоздается. Если вы делаете рефреш в конструкторе VIewModel, то тогда рефреш на весь список выполнится один раз, когда создается вьюмодель, а при повороте экрана не будет лишних ввызовов