# Как правильно получать доступ к ресурсам загруженным в Splash скрин

Tags: java, android, ресурсы

Допустим есть активити и в начале  там грузится например mp3  файл для MediaPlayer, вроде это происходит быстро,  но допустим файл подтягивается из сети и долго грузит.  Ну загрузился он. Теперь по нажатию на определенную кнопку я перехожу на новую активити,  а первая активити ставится системой на onPause (на сколько я знаю в этот момент все ресурсы этой активити очищаются) . И теперь во втором активити я создаю экземпляр первого активити(вернее класса)  и хочу получить доступ к тому файлу который долго гркзился и который я специально подгрузил на сплеш скрине.  Если я создам экземпляр первого класса у меня либо не будет загруженного файла вообще,  либо если его загрузка реализована не в методах жизненного цикла, он начнет грузиться по новой.  (или даже невозможно будет так реаоизовать, чтобы при создании экземпляра он заново грузился). Только если я объявлю ресурс как static, я смогу его использовать в дальнейшем.  Поправьте мои ошибки в размышлениях и скажите как правильно подгружать тяжелый ресурс на сплеш скрине, чтобы потом удобно к нему обращаться?

Ответа нет, обновляю и уточняю вопрос.

**UPD**
Когда при открытии очередного активити идет подгрузка тяжелого файла из ресурсов в оперативку (например файл фоновой музыки). Наверняка будет задержка разворачивания активити, пока подгрузка не завершится. Как я понимаю, такую подгрузку переводят на Splash screen.  за отображение  Splash screen отвечает отдельный класс, в нем подгрузили в переменную требуемый файл и в след активити хотим получить её, эту переменную. Но создав экземпляр класса Splash screen мы её не получим, остается делать переменную static. Но правильно ли это? такой ли подход используется, когда например в тяжелой игре как World of Tanks долго висит сплеш скрин. Врядли они подгружают кучу файлов и делают их статичными.
   Ниже в ответах предложили не менять активити, а менять лишь отображение при помощи setContentView(). Но тогда плакала оперативка, переменные которые уже не нужны будет не убиты сборщиком мусора..А с другой стороны в Splash screen не так и много переменных..Подгрузили все файлы, заменили при помощи setContentView() отображение и поехали.. 
Вопрос в том какой подход верный и используется профессионалами?

Comment: через сервис это делается, то что вы описали вообще не приемлемо в андроид разработке

Comment: Опишите пожалуйста как это происходит. Учтите дело не в загрузке из сети, а нужно грузить из res в оперативку. Но делать это во время сплеш скрин.  Это тоже делается используя сервис?  Пока у меня грузит активити я в доп потоке загружаю файл в класс сервиса? И класс сервиса должен жить до тех пор пока мне требуется доступ к файлу?  Кажется что то не так,  слишком жирно будет создавать сервис, чтобы подгрузить файл из ресурсов в оперативку..

Comment: pavlofff, когда захожу в игру и вижу сплэш скрин на котором тикают проценты загрузки,  загрузка происходит из какого класса? Из того что отображает активити или на фоне есть сервис ?

Answer (score 0):

Когда вы покидаете Активити, то действительно, она становится на паузу. А вот ресурсы очищаются только в том случае, если системе нехватает памяти, если активити будет "смазана" пальцем из списка задач, если в девелоперских настройках есть галочка "убивать активити сразу". Так что, в общем и целом, можно надеяться, что все будет хорошо, но есть маленький шанс, что иногда будет всплывать баг.

Другой вопрос - а сколько нам стоила ресурсов загрузка этого файла? Если дорого, т.е. пользователь может плюнуть и со словами "тормозное говно" удалить наше приложение, то имеет смысл этот файл кешировать на флешку. И совсем не важно, грузите ли вы его внутри Активити или внутри Сервиса (как в общем-то правильней), главное, что после загрузки файл всегда будет доступен и доступен быстро.

Лично мой выбор: не размазывать функциональность приложения на кучу Активити, а делать загрузку и использование внутри одной, переодически показывая/скрывая часть элементов формы или меняя отображаемые вьюшки при помощи setContentView(). И не важно, грузили файлик внутри самой активити или сервиса. Тут главное разобраться кто есть кто и не потеряться, так как если ты создаешь новый инстанс класса, то очевидно, что он будет девственно чистым и в нем ничего не будет (кроме статик-полей, но для них не нужно делать экземпляры).

Comment: подменять разметку через `setContentView()` [гораздо хуже](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/513812/177345), чем прикреплять теги к вьюшкам :). В  итоге такая практика и приводит к: [*мои планшеты с 1 гигом оперативы, которые я покупал как "крутые" несколько лет назад, теперь считаются "устройствами с малым количеством памяти"*](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/716179/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%ba-view-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%82%d1%83%d1%8e-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8e/716200#comment1075628_716200)

Comment: bukkojot, не в этом вопрос. Пусть файл уже находится в апк,  в res пусть лежит тяжелый файл. Я хочу этот файл загрузить заранее во время спеш скрин. А потом уже в других классах иметь к файлу доступ.  Т.е. файл не должен исчезнуть из оперативной памяти. Остается делать его статик? Вопрос в том, как загрузить в оперативку ресурсы которые нужно использовать далее в других активити.  Какая есть практика для того, чтобы не злить юзера долгими подгрузками ресурсов