# Как получить позицию recyclerView для определённого view элемента?

Tags: java, android, recyclerview

У меня есть `RecyclerView`. В layout для итема есть `ImageView` на котором висит `onClick`, вызывающий соответствующий метод в классе, в котором инициализирован этот `RecyclerView`. В аргументе метода я получаю `View` элемент по которому пользователь кликнул. Мне нужно узнать позицию итема в котором расположен этот элемент.

Я посмотрел документацию и там есть метод `getChildAdapterPosition`. Я передал ему `view`, чтобы получить номер итема в котором он расположен, но при клике на этот элемент у меня просто вылетает приложение.

Что я делаю не так?

Вот код метода, обработчика клика:

```
public void onClickHandler(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.status_img:
            if (view.getTag() instanceof Roll) {
                Roll roll = (Roll) view.getTag();
                int recyclerPos = recyclerView.getChildAdapterPosition(view);
            }
            break;
    }

}
```

Comment: в каком методе адаптера расположен этот кликер?

Comment: попробуйте так: `position=recyclerView.findContainingViewHolder(view).getPosition();`

Comment: @AndreyMihalev если это внутри адаптера, то обращаться к виджету - крайне неразумное решение. Если это в активити, то обращаться надо к методу `getAdapterPosition()` холдера, так как `getPosition()` - deprecated, тогда решение имеет смысл.

Comment: @cheerful_weasel  Если кликер указан в разметке, то смотрите вариант как сделано [в этом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/612095/177345). Там для `ListView`, но принцип понятен, думаю.

Comment: @pavloff да, действительно, про getPosition уже прочитал. Спасибо, учту на будущее.

Comment: @pavloff кликер не в методе адаптера расположен, он в разметке, а обработчик в активити. В тег я уже передаю объект, поэтому позицию передать не могу. По объекту я вычисляю индекс массива в котором этот объект находится и на данный момент этого достаточно чтобы узнать позицию адаптера, но это сейчас они совпадают, а позже в адаптере будут ещё итемы другого типа и тогда сравнивать по индексу массива будет уже бесполезно. Поэтому мне и нужен метод вычисления позиции по вьюшке. Попробую сейчас совет с холдером.

Comment: вы можете сделать объект-модель с любым количеством любых полей, заполнить нужными данными и передать ее через тег

Comment: @pavlofff мне не хотелось бы ради этого создавать класс, чтобы передать мой объект и позицию. Метод recyclerView.findContainingViewHolder(view).getAdapterPosition() работает. Так что спасибо за ответы, ваш ответ и ответ AndreyMihalev вместе дали результат который мне и нужен был.

Comment: вы можете написать решение вашей проблемы, нажав "ответить на собственный вопрос", если вы нашли решение самостоятельно.

Comment: @pavlofff я бы не сказал что самостоятельно)) Андерй подсказал решение с position=recyclerView.findContainingViewHolder(view), а вы дополнили его ответ, поправив, что надо не getPosition() вызывать, а getAdapterPosition(). Так что благодаря этим двум советам у меня всё получилось.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В работе RecyclerView для каждого элемента корневого View, добавляется в объект View свойство LayoutParams типа android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.LayoutParams, в котором есть параметр mViewHolder, который содержит служебную информацию о положении View в RecyclerView.

При использовании метода getChildAdapterPosition(View ) происходит примерно следующее:

```
((android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams()).mViewHolder.getLayoutPosition();
```

Так как ImageView, на который повесили onClick, не является корневым View для элемента списка, у ImageView метод getLayoutParams возвращает объект не приводимый к типу android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.LayoutParams.
Тем самым возникает ошибка каста и падение приложения.

Пример как можно лучше решить вопрос:
http://whiteshieldsoftware.blogspot.ru/2016/01/recyclerview-6.html