# Нажатие на динамически созданные блоки (Layout)

Tags: android, android-studio

Добрый день. Прошу помощи, так как перечитал много инфы, а ответа не нашел. И просьба не пинать сильно, так как я только начинающий )))

Вот такая задача: получить с удаленного сервиса json-данные, поместить данные в layout. Таких данных может быть много, следовательно layout`ы надо создавать динамически.

Сначала сделал так: по циклу разобрал json-массив. и в цикле начал создавать динамически разметку с layout`ами и textview`шками. куда помещал информацию из массива. Все бы ни чего, правда код получился громоздкий ужасно. И не понял как написать обработчик onclick, что бы при нажатии на основной layout открыть новую активность и передать туда данные из этого layout`а.

Почитал по разным источникам и переделал по другому. Создал дополнительный файл разметки:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
android:background="@drawable/main_background"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout_info"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:onClick="onLayoutClick"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_data"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingEnd="5dp"
        android:paddingStart="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        tools:ignore="RtlSymmetry">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/separator"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1.9"
            android:background="@drawable/separator"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/type_customer_address"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/type"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:paddingStart="10dp"
                android:textColor="@color/material_drawer_primary_text" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/customer"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:paddingStart="10dp"
                android:textColor="@color/material_drawer_secondary_text"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/address"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:paddingStart="10dp"
                android:textColor="@color/material_drawer_secondary_text"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/numer_date"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_weight="1.5"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/numer"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:background="#00aa00"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:textSize="8sp"
                tools:ignore="SmallSp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/date"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:background="#00aa00"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:textSize="8sp"
                tools:ignore="SmallSp" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/info_badges"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingEnd="5dp"
        tools:ignore="RtlSymmetry">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/info"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.45"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/badges"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:layout_weight="1.55"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/badges1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:contentDescription="@string/map_task"
                app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_mapmode" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<View
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="2dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:background="@color/dropShadow" />
```

А в цикле через адаптер обрабатываю данные и вывожу в основной активности:

```
String url = "https://site.ru/task_user.php";
        String json = "{\"user_id\":\""+mSettings.getString(APP_PREFERENCES_ID, "")+"\"}";
        HttpPostGetActivity handler = new HttpPostGetActivity();
        String result = "";
        try {
            result = handler.execute(url, json).get();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        ListView listViewAd = findViewById(R.id.LayoutTextView);

        // Упаковываем данные
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> data = new ArrayList<>();
        HashMap<String, Object> map;

        String[] resultParts = result.split("::");
        for (String resultPart : resultParts) {

            try {
                JSONObject dataJsonObj = new JSONObject(resultPart);
                JSONObject taskData = dataJsonObj.getJSONObject("Data");
                taskId = taskData.getString("id");
                JSONObject taskDateObj = taskData.getJSONObject("date");
                taskDate = taskDateObj.getString("todo");
                JSONObject taskType = taskData.getJSONObject("type");
                nameType = taskType.getString("name");
                JSONObject taskCustomer = taskData.getJSONObject("customer");
                taskCustomerId = taskCustomer.getString("id");
                taskCustomerFullName = taskCustomer.getString("fullName");
                JSONObject taskAddressObj = taskData.getJSONObject("address");
                taskAddressText = taskAddressObj.getString("text");
                taskAddressCity = taskAddressObj.getString("cityId");
                taskDescription = taskData.getString("description");

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        resultPart,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            map = new HashMap<>();
            map.put("type", nameType);
            map.put("customer", taskCustomerFullName);
            map.put("address", taskAddressText);
            map.put("numer", taskId);
            map.put("date", taskDate);
            map.put("info", taskDescription);
            data.add(map);

        }

        // Массив имен атрибутов, из которых будут читаться данные
        String[] from = {
                "type",
                "customer",
                "address",
                "numer",
                "date",
                "info"
        };

        // Массив идентификаторов компонентов, в которые будем вставлять данные
        int[] to = {
                R.id.type,
                R.id.customer,
                R.id.address,
                R.id.numer,
                R.id.date,
                R.id.info
        };

        // создаем адаптер
        SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, data, R.layout.layout_block,
                from, to);

        // Устанавливаем адаптер для списка
        listViewAd.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно прописать обработчик onclick.
То есть получается, что динамически создаются несколько layout. Если в xml-разметке прописать onclick, то он срабатывает одинаково. На какой бы лайоут не нажми. Как определить по какому именно лайоуту произведено нажатие и забрать данные из этого лайоута для передачи в другую активность.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/612052/177345

Comment: если я все верно понял, то в том примере, что вы дали, имеется одна определенная кнопка со своим id. А если таких кнопок формируется динамически несколько и получается, что у них у всех один и тот же id будет?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

вопрос решается просто.

1. Сразу после того, как установили адаптер:

   `// Устанавливаем адаптер для списка
   listViewAd.setAdapter(adapter);`

Прописываем слушателя:

```
`listViewAd.setOnItemClickListener (listener);`
```

2. В той же активности, где устанавливается адаптер, пишем:

   AdapterView.OnItemClickListener listener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){

   ```
   @Override
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){
       ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.type)).getText();
       //or do your stuff
       Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.type)).getText(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }};
   ```

Все. И теперь можно получать любые данные из блоков. Единственный момент, что ц меня в верху, как можете видеть, был прописан onclick на layout. Вот его надо удалить. С ним работать не будет.

Ответ нашел вот тут: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4461134/android-listview-adapter-onclicklistener-issue

Answer (score 1):

Используйте `RecyclerView` для решений вашей задачи. 
В `.xml` вашего ViewHolder(a) добавьте кнопку и повесьте слушателя.

Создайте `MyInterface` для вашего `MyFragment` / `MyActivity`, добавьте в него метод, например:

**MyInterface:**

```
public interface MyInterface {

    void goToNextActivity(String data);
}
```

**MyFragment:**

```
public class MyFragment implements MyInterface{

  private MyAdapter adapter;


  @Nullable
  @Override
  public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my, container, false);
        ...
        adapter = new MyAdapter(someDate);
        adapter.setDelegateFragment(new WeakReference<>(this));
        ..
        return v;
    }

...

@Override
    public void goToNextActivity(String data) {
        //Ваш код на то что вы хотите сделать
    }
...

}
```

Он будет получать данные из вашего `ViewHolder`(a) и делать все что вы ему скажите.

Создайте делегат с типом ссылки `WeakReference` в `Adapter`(e) и `ViewHolder`(e).

```
private WeakReference<MyInterface> delegateFragment;

public void setDelegateFragment (WeakReference<MyInterface> delegateFragment){
     this.delegateFragment = delegateFragment;
  }
```

После того как вы передадите ваши данные в `adapter`, сделайте set к ранее созданному `delegat`(у) в `adapter`(е), а после из `adapter`(a) сделайте `set` к `ViewHolder`(у) в методе `onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position)`

Answer (score 0):

```
ListView listViewAd = findViewById(R.id.LayoutTextView);
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
       // Тут имеем доступ к data[position]
       // Создаём интент, кладём в него нужные данные и стартуем другое активити
    }
});
```

Comment: "Тут имеем доступ к data[position]" - будьте добры чуть подробнее. я для теста пытаюсь вывести: 
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
Но пока ни чего не выходит.

Comment: @Shotlandec, для начала поставь breakpoint и убедись, что эта строка отрабатывает. И уведомления требуют UI поток, поэтому в `onItemClick` используй 
`runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
@Override
 public void run() {
 // Тут Toast.makeText...               
 }
 });`

Comment: ноль реакции:
`runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        } });`

Comment: @Shotlandec А breakpoint ловится на этой строке?

Comment: доходит вот до этой строки, а дальше не идет: `runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {`

Comment: @Shotlandec я даже не знаю, что тут ещё может быть. Попробуй в логи выводить position