# Что лучше использовать: атрибут onClick или реализация интерфейса onClickListener?

Tags: java, android

начал изучать android разработку и у меня возник вопрос, что лучше использовать - атрибут android:onClick, а метод прописывать в main, или реализовывать интерфейс onClickListener и использовать activity как объект ?

Comment: Что удобней - то и используйте. Работает одинаково. Я бы не засорял xml

Comment: Не совсем понятны "последствия" использования обоих вариантов слушателей. В android нет и не может быть метода-точки входа `main()` и активити нельзя использовать, как клиентский объект (точнее, это будет "мертвое" активити)

Comment: Хотя бы потому что потом, когда ваше приложение разрастется, будет гораздо проще работать с добавленными слешателями, когда это сделано програмно. Добавляя через хмл ничего плохого не будет, просто вы наверняка добавите путаницы там где она не нужна.

Answer (score 2):

Используйте программную реализацию. В реальном мире почти никто не использует назначение слушателей в разметке обычным способом. Причин несколько:

1. В активити обычно нет кнопок кроме меню и/или кнопок навигации (табы, например), а они обычно управляются своими слушателями нажатий.
2. Обычно активити используется как контейнер для фрагментов. Весь интерфейс как раз в них и находится и в них (фрагментах) такой способ указания слушателя просто не работает, ибо и не должен.
3. Также часто слушатели нажатий находятся на кнопках внутри элементов каких-то списков. Там это тоже работать не будет.
4. Если нравится назначать слушатели из разметки то надо брать `AndroidDataBinding` библиотеку и делать через неё. Но это уже скорее про архитектурный подход (`MVVM` vs `MVP`).

**Итого:**

Способ придуман на заре эры андроида когда не было фрагментов и устоявшихся подходов к проектированию и для быстрых прототипов это казалось полезным. Сейчас в этой возможности нет нужды и её не стоит использовать.

Comment: По пункту 3 - со списком на активити работать будет и иногда это [самое простое решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/612095/177345). Вообще нет никакой разницы, использовать программный способ или через атрибут - при сборке\компиляции второй вариант преобразуется в первый