# Многоэлементный ListView. События нажатия на разные элементы

Tags: java, android, listview

Есть ListView, в котором 2 элемента.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
            android:text="TextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/name" android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <CheckBox
            android:text="CheckBox"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/check" android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Вот так я отображаю свой String массив в ListView.

```
   ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), R.layout.markers_list, R.id.name, name_mark);
            list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Как обращаться к LV с 1 элементом, я знаю. Но как мне отдельно расчленить, что должно происходить при нажатии на TextView, а что при нажатии на ChekBox? 
Просто ступор.

UPD.

Отказался от Фрагмента и начал выводить ListView в Активити.
Вывел. Написал метод в Активити

```
   public void qwe(View v){
        TextView tx = v.findViewById(R.id.name);
        tx.setText("sdfg");
    }
```

и повесил его на кнопку

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <CheckBox
            android:text="CheckBox"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/check" android:layout_weight="1"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false" android:onClick="qwe"/>
    <TextView
            android:text="TextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/name" android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Где ошибка?

Comment: нужно писать кастомный адаптер и там вешать слушатели на [каждый элемент айтема отдельно](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/612095/177345)

Comment: @pavlofff а можно пример или ссылку?

Comment: @pavlofff во фрагменте =(

Comment: тогда [такая схема](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28798273/7566397) - слушатели на элементы айтема в кастомном адаптере, в примере это кнопка, но виджет может быть любой. если требуется событие о клике еще и передать в активити, то нужно в адаптере организовать колбэк на событие

Comment: @pavlofff скажите, а как программно можно сделать нажатие на ВСЕ айтемы списка?

Comment: @pavlofff нет, не для чекбоксов. нужна именно имитация нажатия в коде на основные айтемы, которые сформировались из заданного массива. вроде понятно объяснил... нужно программно setOnItemClickListener на всех итемы.

Comment: @pavlofff знаю, что нажаите делается через View.performClick(); как получить View всего LV ?

Comment: @pavlofff посмотрел ссылку на кастомный адаптер. весь OnClick в другом классе. может есть примеры адаптера, чтобы onClick доп.кнопок был там, где и LV вызывается? слишком много чего надо передавать в кастомный адаптер тогда.

Comment: @pavlofff отказался от Фрагмента и переделал на активити, но там опять ошибка. гляньте UPD в мейн-посте.

Comment: дело в том, что при разработке может появляться более, чем одна причина ошибки, поэтому в вопросах с ошибками, нужно [прикладывать стектрейс](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/797531/177345) этой ошибки, чтобы было понятно, в чем именно дело