# RecyclerView & CardView onClickListener

Tags: android

Помогите пожалуйста не могу ни как решить проблему с реализаций клика на КардВью, уже все перепробовал не получается. Подскажите где ошибка и как исправить ее. Нужно перейти на новый фрагмент при клике на кардвью.

```
public class RVAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RVAdapter.PersonViewHolder> {

public static class PersonViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    CardView cv;
    TextView personName;
    TextView personAge;
    ImageView personPhoto;
    OnItemClickListener cvClickListener;

    public interface OnItemClickListener{
        void onItemClicked(int position);
    }


    PersonViewHolder(View itemView, OnItemClickListener clickListener) {
        super(itemView);
        cv = (CardView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.cv);
        personName = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.person_name);
        personAge = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.person_age);
        personPhoto = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.person_photo);

        cvClickListener = clickListener;

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        cvClickListener.onItemClicked(getAdapterPosition());

        }
    }

List<Person> persons;

public RVAdapter(List<Person> persons){
    this.persons = persons;
}

@Override
public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
}

@Override
public PersonViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item, viewGroup, false);
    PersonViewHolder personViewHolder = new PersonViewHolder(view);
    return personViewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(PersonViewHolder personViewHolder, int i) {
    personViewHolder.personName.setText(persons.get(i).name);
    personViewHolder.personAge.setText(persons.get(i).age);
    personViewHolder.personPhoto.setImageResource(persons.get(i).photoId);


}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return persons.size();
}
```

}

Comment: Кажется у вас оно не должно компилироваться. У вас в конструкторе 2 аргумента, включая слушатель клика, но вы используете другой конструктор для холдера

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/423291/177345