# Обработка нажатия элемента RecyclerView

Tags: android, recyclerview, recyclerview.adapter

К примеру, у меня есть список элементов в RecyclerView:

```
Элемент1 (id1 Title1 Date1)   
Элемент2 (id2 Title2 Date2)   
Элемент3 (id3 Title3 Date3)
```

Нужно по нажатию на отдельный элемент открывать фрагмент, в который передаются соответствующие значения. Допустим, нажали на `Элемент2`, открывается фрагмент и передаются значения `Title2` и `Date2`, чтобы я их использовал и тд.
Читая многие ресурсы, не понимаю как сделать это все по науке, ибо в различных источниках, кто как вешает слушатель, а я так и не понял, как организовать то, что мне нужно. Буду признателен за оказанную помощь! :)

Comment: Вы так же как и все можете "повесить" слушатель [разными способами](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/423291/177345), в зависимости от решаемых задач, нет единственно правильного "по науке" - как удобнее реализовать именно вашу задачу, так и делайте.

Comment: Посмотрите, пожалуйста, мой ответ ниже. Правильный ли этот способ?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Общение между фрагментами должно идти через активити, которая хостит эти фрагменты. Для общения фрагмента с активити необходимо создать интерфейс, реализовать его в активити, в onAttach фрагмента приводить контекст к интерфейсу, и дергать методы интерфейса при манипуляциях во фрагменте. Активити может обращаться к фрагменту непосредственно к его методам. Упрощенно так:

```
interface ModelOpener {
    void openModel(Model model);
}

class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ModelOpener {
    @Override
    void openModel(Model model){
        Fragment f = ModelFragment.newInstance(model);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(..., f).commit();
    }
}

class ModelListFragment extends Fragment {
   class Holder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
      ...
   }
   @Override
   void onAttach(Context context){
       super.onAttach(context);
       if(context instanceof ModelOpener){
           mModelOpener = (ModelOpener)mModelOpener;
       }
   }

   @Override
   void onViewCreated(View view){
       ...
       mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.list);
   }
   @Override
   void onActivityCreated(...){
       ...
       adapter = new RecyclerView.Adapter<Holder>(){
           ...
           @Override
           void onBindVewHolder(Holder holder, position){
               holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                   @Override
                   public void onClick(View view) {
                       if(mModelOpener!=null)
                           mModelOpener.openModel(
                               list.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()));
                   }
               });
           }
       };
       mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
   }
}

class ModelFragment extends Fragment {
   public static ModelFragment newInstance(Model model){
      Bundle args = new Bundle();
      // помещаем модель в аргументы. тут как удобно: сериализуем модель Serializable, Parcelable и вообще в Json. или передаем только id, а фрагмент сам например в базе возьмет необходимые данные
      //например
      args.putString("title",model.getText());
      fragment = new ModelFragment();
      fragment.setArguments(args);
      return fragment;
   }

   ...

   @Override
   void onActivityCreated(...){
      // и здесь достаем аргументы
      // например
      mTitleTextView.setText(getArguments().getString("title"));
   }
}
```

ЗЫ писал в окне редактора, могут быть опечатки

Comment: Т.е. данный метод подойдет если у меня 1 активити с framelayout и 2 фрагмента, правильно? Я недавно начал андроид учить, немного сложно написано, но я попробую! потом дам ответ :)

Comment: Да, можно в любой комбинации фрагментов на одной активити. Почитайте книжку Харди и Филлипса, там есть несколько глав про это.

Answer (score 0):

В общем, я организовал это все в классе `Adapter`, в методе `onBindViewHolder`:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final Adapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Model model = list.get(position); //ArrayList<Model> list;
    holder.title.setText(model.getText());
    holder.date.setText(model.getDate());
    holder.view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Log.d("logs", "title-"+ holder.title.getText()+", date-"+holder.date.getText());
        }
    });

}
```

ViewHolder вложенный класс в адаптере. Логи показывают, что все работает. По нажатию на отдельный элемент в списке, достаются корректные значения title and date. Если есть способ умнее и главное- правильнее это сделать, то просьба поправить меня :)

Comment: Могу сказать, что данные нужно получать всегда из источника, а не представления (не `holder.title.getText()`, а `model.getText()` в логе). Для запуска активити этого было бы достаточно, но фрагмент запускать из адаптера будет несколько проблематично. Самым приемлемым в данном случае будет [решение Yura Ivanov](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/715925/177345)

Comment: Теперь у меня другой вопрос) обработку нажатия я сделал, ок. А как сейчас при нажатии, заполнить FrameLayout другим фрагментом :)) ведь метод getSupportFragmentManager() вызвать нельзя)

Answer (score 0):

Я бы рекомендовал объявить свой интерфейс внутри адаптера и принимать его в конструкторе адаптера

```
public interface Listener{
    void onItemClick(int position); //можно добавить и саму модель ,Model model
}
```

Привязывать листенер нужно в методе адаптера `onCreateViewHolder` (что позволит избежать многократного пересоздания объектов `View.OnClickListener` в случае объявления в методе `onBindViewHolder`)

```
public abstract VH onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    //...
    view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            final int pos = holder.getAdapterPosition();
            if (pos != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                listener.onItemClick(pos);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

А в самом классе активити/фрагмента, где используется адаптер - уже и реализовать обработчик. Таким образом при изменении логики обработки нажатия, код адаптера останется неизменным, поменяется только код обработчика.

Answer (score -1):

Почитай что такое "Intent". С помощью него можно передавать данные.

Comment: У меня одно активити и 2 фрагмента. 
в первом фрагменте список элементов в ресайклвью, во втором фрагменте - подробное описание отдельно взятого элемента

Comment: пример использования явно не повредил бы ответу.