# как использовать OnClick не в адаптере?

Tags: java, android, adapter

Раньше я всегда создавал для каждого класса свой адаптер, честно говоря меня это уже начало бесить. Куча кода и неправильное понятие паттерна адаптера. Но все из - за гугловских примеров по реализации recycleView и паттерна viewHolder.

Теперь у меня такой вопрос. Есть у меня 5 классов и все они используют класс `PhotoAdapter`. Так вот как вынести функционал нажатий из адаптера, чтобы адаптер оставался лишь адаптером. Так как каждый элемент класса выполняет свое действие при нажатии. Или что мне писать 20 строчек IF?

Comment: Это не то. В listView можно было использовать setonlisitems как то - так. А в recyclerView нет такого.

Comment: что если прочитать вопрос-дубликат повнимательнее? там как раз написано, как реализовать аналог колбэка onItemClickListener самому для RecyclerView. В любом случае решение лучше вам никто не предложит, за исключением готовой библиотеки класса-адаптера для RecyclerView, во многих из них реализован колбэк в активити.

Comment: @pavlofff, а вы не знаете почему гугл это сразу не сделала как с listVIew?

Comment: в общем-то [знаю](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/423291/177345)