# Реализовать выбор элемента RecyclerView

Tags: android

Есть такой класс адаптер для вывода данных из БД в RecyclerView

```
public class BludaAdapter extends RecyclerViewCursorAdapter<BludaAdapter.BludaViewHolder> {


    /**
     * Index of the name column.
     */

    /**
     * Constructor.
     * @param context The Context the Adapter is displayed in.
     */
    public BludaAdapter(Context context) {
        super(context);

        setupCursorAdapter(null, 0, R.layout.item, false);
    }

    /**
     * Returns the ViewHolder to use for this adapter.
     */
    @Override
    public BludaViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new BludaViewHolder(mCursorAdapter.newView(mContext, mCursorAdapter.getCursor(), parent));
    }

    /**
     * Moves the Cursor of the CursorAdapter to the appropriate position and binds the view for
     * that item.
     */
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(BludaViewHolder holder, int position) {
        // Move cursor to this position
        mCursorAdapter.getCursor().moveToPosition(position);

        // Set the ViewHolder
        setViewHolder(holder);

        // Bind this view
        mCursorAdapter.bindView(null, mContext, mCursorAdapter.getCursor());

    }

    /**
     * ViewHolder used to display a movie name.
     */
    public class BludaViewHolder extends RecyclerViewCursorViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        public final TextView txtBludo;
        public final TextView txtRecept;
        public final LinearLayout lv;
        public final Button btnLike;

        public BludaViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);

            txtBludo = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtBludo);
            txtRecept = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtRecept);
            lv = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.lv);
            btnLike = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnLike);

            lv.setOnClickListener(this);
            btnLike.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void bindCursor(Cursor cursor) {
            //int id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("id"));
            String bludo = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("bludo"));
            String recept = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("recept"));
            int like = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("like"));

            txtBludo.setText(bludo);
            txtRecept.setText(recept);
            Log.d("TAG", cursor.getPosition() + "");

            if (like == 1) {
                btnLike.setText("В избранном");
            } else {
                btnLike.setText("Нет в избранном");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            int position = getAdapterPosition();
            if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                switch (v.getId()) {
                    case R.id.lv:
                        itemClick(position);
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

        private void itemClick(int position){
            txtBludo.setText(txtBludo.getText().toString() + " " + position);
        }
    }
}
```

Как из этого ответа [Как добавить обработчик нажатия на элемент в RecyclerView?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/423286/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82-%D0%B2-recyclerview/423291#423291) по второму варианту реализовать клики:

1. Клик на сам пункт списка, чтобы при клике открывалось новое активити
2. Клик на btnLike, чтобы при клике на эту кнопку в MainActivity можно было что-то выполнить (в частности добавить или удалить этот пункт в избранное т.е. обновить поле Like в таблице Bluda)

Comment: Есть [несколько вариантов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/423291/177345) обработать клики. Если вы используете сторонню библиотеку, лучше указать на нее ссылку в вопросе. PS:вам не нужно заполнять `Bundle`, если вы его не используете, просто передавайте null - `getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(LOADER_BLUDA, null, this);`, а код с созданием `Bundle` удалите

Comment: Исправила вопрос

Comment: А если у меня item содержит кнопку "Like", которая будет добавлять в избранное или удалять из избранного меняя значение поля like в таблице bluda. Можно ли реализовать этот функционал прямо в адаптере? Т.е. создавать переменную класса DBHelper, запросы писать? К каким ошибкам это может привести?

Comment: в адаптере не стоит работать с БД

Comment: Я бы тоже не хотела работать в адаптере с бд. Поэтому вариант реализации кликов в активити для меня предпочтительнее

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В активити:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements BludaAdapter.OnItemClickListener{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final RecyclerView rv = view.findViewById(R.id.list);
        rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        BludaAdapter adapter = new BludaAdapter(this);
        rv.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(long id) {
        // переменная id - ID записи, по которой кликнули в списке
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityTwo.class);
        intent.putExtra("id", id);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFavoriteButtonClick(long id, boolean isFavorite) {
         // переменная id - ID записи, по которой кликнули (для обращения к БД)
         // переменная isFavorite - состояние избранного в записи перед нажатием на кнопку
         if (isFavorite) {
                // что делать, если запись в избранном
         } else {
                // что делать, если запись не в избранном
         }
    }
}
```

При нажатии на пункт в списке сработает метод `onItemClick()`, при нажатии на кнопку - `onFavoriteButtonClick()`

Адаптер:

```
public class BludaAdapter extends RecyclerViewCursorAdapter<BludaAdapter.BludaViewHolder> {

    OnItemClickListener mItemClickListener;

    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(long id);
        void onFavoriteButtonClick(long id, boolean isFavorite);
    }

    public BludaAdapter(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setupCursorAdapter(null, 0, R.layout.item, false);
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(final OnItemClickListener mItemClickListener) {
        this.mItemClickListener = mItemClickListener;
    }

    @Override
    public BludaViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
     ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(BludaViewHolder holder, int position) {
     ...
    }

    public class BludaViewHolder extends RecyclerViewCursorViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        public final TextView txtBludo;
        public final TextView txtRecept;
        public final Button btnLike;
        int like;
        long id;

        public BludaViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);

            txtBludo = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtBludo);
            txtRecept = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtRecept);
            btnLike = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnLike);

            view.setOnClickListener(this);
            btnLike.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void bindCursor(Cursor cursor) {
            // переменные id, like переносим в поле класса-холдера, чтобы был доступ из всех методов
            id = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex("id"));
            like = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("like")); 
            String bludo = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("bludo"));
            String recept = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("recept"));
            txtBludo.setText(bludo);
            txtRecept.setText(recept);
            // конструкцию с if-else упрощаем
            btnLike.setText((like == 1)? "В избранном":"Нет в избранном");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

                switch (v.getId()) {
                    case R.id.btnLike:
                        mItemClickListener.onFavoriteButtonClick(id, like == 1);
                        break;
                    default:
                        mItemClickListener.onItemClick(id);
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Можно уточнить? Например у меня в таблице нумерация в поле id  начинается с 1, а позиция самого курсора как я понимаю будет начинаться с 0. И у меня вопрос в MainActivity при передаче id во второе активити что будет содержать?  Id записи в таблице или позицию курсора?

Comment: Вроде поняла. Сейчас буду смотреть

Comment: @НатальяСергеевна Метод из адаптера возвращает именно ID записи, а не позицию. При работе с БД вам вообще нужно забыть о всяких позициях: в курсоре, в списке и где бы то ни было. В реляционной БД есть только один маркер - ID записи, с ней и работают (обновляют запись, удаляют и тд). Так же нужно понимать, что ID записи и позиция где бы то ни было - совсем не одно и тоже. Например, при удалении записи, ID следующих за ним записей не изменится (не уменьшится на 1), а позиция в списке - изменится

Comment: Я понимаю.. Сейчас попробую у себя реализовать все это

Comment: У меня выдало ошибку java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it. на строке id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("id")); Что это означает?

Comment: Ну int можно заменить на long в любое время ведь. У меня же пока тестовый пример. Я так поняла эта ошибка означает что не может найти поле id ? или что

Comment: сейчас создам другой вопрос, связанный с кликом. С Этой ошибкой разобралась сама