# Как проверять, добавлен ли объект в избранное или нет?

Tags: java, android

В активити, к кнопке (к обычной button) прибил следующую команду, при вызове которой, будут взяты данные и сохранены в "Избранное".

```
Favorites.addFavorite(Streamer.getInstance().getStation().getStationUrl());
```

рядом разместил такую же кнопку, но только для удаления станции из избранного.

```
Favorites.removeFavorite(Streamer.getInstance().getStation().getStationUrl());
```

сам класс

```
public class Favorites {
private static List<String> favoriteUrls = null;

private static File getFavoritesPath() {
    return new File(CacheManager.getRoot(), "favorites");
}

public static void load() {
    Sack.open(String[].class, getFavoritesPath()).load(new Sack.Listener<String[]>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(final Sack.Status status, final String[] favorites) {
            favoriteUrls = new ArrayList<String>();
            if (favorites == null)
                return;
            for (String favorite : favorites)
                favoriteUrls.add(favorite);
        }
    });
}

public static List<Station> getFavorites() {
    final List<Station> favorites = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String url : favoriteUrls)
        favorites.add(Directory.getStation(url));
    Station.sort(favorites);
    return favorites;
}

public static void addFavorite(final String favoriteUrl) {
    if (!favoriteUrls.contains(favoriteUrl)) {
        favoriteUrls.add(favoriteUrl);
        commit();
    }
}

public static void removeFavorite(final String favoriteUrl) {
    if (favoriteUrls.contains(favoriteUrl)) {
        favoriteUrls.remove(favoriteUrl);
        commit();
    }
}

protected static void commit() {
    final String[] urls = favoriteUrls.toArray(new String[favoriteUrls.size()]);
    Sack.open(String[].class, getFavoritesPath()).commit(urls);
} }
```

**Вопрос в следующем:** Как проверять, добавлен ли объект в избранное или нет, и показывать уже сразу нужную кнопку, либо для удаления, либо для добавления в объекта в избранное.

Потому что две кнопки **Добавить в Избранное** и **Удалить из Избранного** в одном месте, это не совсем правильно и целесообразно. Заранее спасибо за помощь!.

Comment: лучше всего не выделять отдельную коллекцию под избранное, а в модели данных,которая хранится в общей коллекции, добавить флаг (Boolean переменную) избранного . Тогда получить избранное можно просто выбрав значения по этому флагу, а проверить в избранном или нет простым if. Соответственно от содержимого показывать нужную кнопку. При текущей реализации алгоритм будет крайне неэффективный, так как вам не остаётся ничего, как проверять каждый элемент основной коллекции на то, не содержится ли такое же значение в коллекции избранного.

Comment: @pavlofff, Так у меня не проверяется каждый элемент основной коллекции. Я обращаюсь только к самой коллекции избранного, посмотреть есть ли в ней требуемый объект. Проверка, есть или нет объекта в избранном происходит не для всех объектов , а только для того, который в данный момент используется (воспроизводимая станция)

Comment: Сделал следующий метод:   public static void checkFavorite(final String favoriteUrl) {
        if (favoriteUrls.contains(favoriteUrl)) {
            PlayerView.favoriteAdd.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            PlayerView.favoriteDelete.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            PlayerView.favoriteAdd.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            PlayerView.favoriteDelete.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

Comment: @pavlofff, не знаю правильно ли я сделал его вообще, но проверять он проверяет и скрывает вьюшку как положено

Comment: из за неправильной организации вы производите поиск совпадения по ВСЕЙ коллекции каждый раз - это очень неэффективно и отнимает большой ресурс, в то время, как можно просто для каждой станции хранить признак (флаг) - в избранном она или нет и никакой отдельной коллекции избранного вообще не нужно и никакого перебора по коллекции тоже не нужно.

Comment: этот флаг (boolean) true или false я могу хранить в модели данных, Если я правильно понял, то это в том месте, где у меня лежат все данные. А лежат они у меня в папке assets, к которой как мне писали ранее невозможно подключиться и изменять данные .json файла со всеми моими данными. Или я не правильно вас понял?)

Comment: Тогда как этот флаг будет меняться, в заисимости от того , добавил себе пользователь станцию или нет? Я же не могу изменять данные, которые у меня считываются с assets

Comment: Вы поняли правильно и в assets действительно нельзя писать данные. А где вы храните избранное? ведь коллекция с избранным будет уничтожена при закрытии приложения. вообще вам нужно хранить не в assets, а в БД, например, и с ней работать. В вашем случае очень подойдет ObjectBox - это очень простая, быстрая и легкая noSQL база от Green robot, которая работает напрямую с моделями данных. При старте заполнить ее вы можете и из статичного json

Comment: @pavlofff, данные сохраняю с помощью Sack (A simple data store for Android) [github.com/mdellavo/Sack](https://github.com/mdellavo/Sack)

Comment: ну и сохраняйте туда все данные, а не только избранное, хотя я бы серьезно подумал в сторону Objectbox - он намного удобнее в работе, чем json.

Comment: так же вам не нужны **две** кнопки у которых менятся видимость, а нужна одна, в которой меняется текст (добавить/удалить) и в ней логика действий в зависимости от текущего состояния (фактически просто инвертировать флаг в модели)

Answer (score 5):

Для более правильного решения вашего вопроса вам нужно полностью пересмотреть структуру вашего проекта. Так, сохранять избранное в отдельный список очень не эффективно, так как на выяснение - в избранном элемент или нет, уходит неоправданно много ресурса. Так же, делать две отдельные кнопки для добавления в избранное, либо удаления из него - скрывая одну и показывая другую, тоже очень неэффективно.

Предлагаю более оптимальное решение.
Во первых, избавиться от отдельного списка избранного, добавив к модели элемента основного списка флаг состояния (булевую переменную) - в избранном данный элемент или нет. Это во много раз уменьшит потребление ресурса и сильно упростит логику.
Во вторых, вместо двух, скрывающихся по очереди кнопок, использовать одну, в которой менять текст в зависимости от текущего состояния элемента.

Предлагаю простой код, реализующий эти идеи, на основе базы данных [ObjectBox](http://objectbox.io) для примера (как [подключить в проект](http://objectbox.io/documentation/introduction/#Gradlesetup)). При желании вы можете легко модифицировать его под свою структуру хранения данных.
Для примера у нас список некоторых станций (для простоты заполнены только поля с названиями станций), а под списком находится кнопка-селектор, последовательное нажатие на которую переключает вид на все станции, либо на только избранные станции. В каждом пункте станций есть кнопка, нажатие на которую либо добавляет станцию в избранное (если ее там нет), либо убирает ее из избранного (если она там была). Комментарии в коде должны прояснить основные моменты логики работы.

Сначала создаем модель данных для ObjectBox (стандартный POJO с геттерами\сеттерами):

```
@Entity
public class Station {
    @Id long id;
    String Name;
    String url;
    boolean favorite;

    public Station() {
    }
    public Station(String name) {
        Name = name;
    }    
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }    
    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }    
    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }    
    public void setName(String name) {
        Name = name;
    }    
    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }    
    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }    
    public boolean isFavorite() {
        return favorite;
    }    
    public void setFavorite(boolean favorite) {
        this.favorite = favorite;
    }
}
```

*примечание: класс-модель для ObjectBox обязательно должна содержать поле с аннотацией @id и конструктор без аргументов.*

Класс активити, где происходит вся магия:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String [] stations = {"Station1","Station2","Station3","Station4","Station5","Station6","Station7","Station8","Station9"};
    BoxStore boxStore;
    Box<Station> stationsBox;
    StationAdapter adapter;
    Button buttonSelect;
    boolean onlyFavorite; // показывать весь список или только избранное

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        boxStore = MyObjectBox.builder().androidContext(this).build();
        stationsBox = boxStore.boxFor(Station.class);

        if (stationsBox.getAll().isEmpty()) {
            // если база не заполнена, то заполняем данными
             for(String station:stations){
                 stationsBox.put(new Station(station));
             }
        }

        buttonSelect = findViewById(R.id.buttonSelect);
        RecyclerView rv = findViewById(R.id.list);

        buttonSelect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // переключаем отображение всего списка или только избранного
                onlyFavorite = !onlyFavorite;
                String textButton = onlyFavorite? "All Station": "Only favorite station";
                buttonSelect.setText(textButton);
                //обновляем список
                getDataset(onlyFavorite);
            }
        });

        rv.setHasFixedSize(true);
        rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        ArrayList<Station> dataset = getDataset(onlyFavorite);
        adapter = new StationAdapter(dataset);
        rv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    private ArrayList<Station> getDataset(boolean onlyFavorite) {
        // делаем выборку в БД. Показывать все станции или только избранные
        ArrayList<Station> dataset = (ArrayList<Station>) (onlyFavorite? stationsBox.query().equal(Station_.favorite, true).build().find(): stationsBox.getAll());
        //обновляем список
        if (adapter != null) adapter.notifyList(dataset);
        return dataset;
    }

    public void onClickFavorite(View view){
        // здесь обрабатываем клик на кнопке избранного в айтеме списка
        // метод вызывается по атрибуту android:onClick xml-разметки айтема

        // Получаем ID станции, на которой кликнули кнопку избранного
        long id = (long) view.getTag();
        // инвертируем отметку избранного
        Station station = stationsBox.get(id);
        station.setFavorite(!station.isFavorite());
        stationsBox.put(station);
        //обновляем список
        getDataset(onlyFavorite);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        boxStore.close();
    }
}
```

*примечание: при использовании ObjectBox, чтобы класс `MyObjectBox` не показывал ошибки, нужно сбилдить проект (Build -> rebuild project), так как это автогенерируемый класс и для его создания нужно собрать проект.*

Адаптер для вывода в список:

```
public class StationAdapter extends  RecyclerView.Adapter<StationAdapter.ViewHolder>{

    ArrayList<Station> stations;

    public StationAdapter(ArrayList<Station> stations) {
        this.stations = stations;
    }

    @Override
    public StationAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(StationAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Station station = stations.get(position);
        holder.name.setText(station.getName());
        // Надпись на кнопке избранного
        // Если не в избранном, то "добавить". Если в избранном, то "убрать"
        String buttonText = station.isFavorite()? "Delete favorite": "Add favorite";
        holder.buttonFavorite.setText(buttonText);
        // отправляем в активити ID станции, на которой нажали кнопку избранного
        holder.buttonFavorite.setTag(station.getId());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return stations.size();
    }

    public void notifyList(ArrayList<Station> stations){
        this.stations = stations;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        final TextView name;
        final Button buttonFavorite;
        ViewHolder(View view){
            super(view);
            name = view.findViewById(R.id.name);
            buttonFavorite = view.findViewById(R.id.buttonFavorite);
        }
    }
}
```

*примечание: для связи с активити по нажатию кнопки используется слушатель, назначенный в xml-разметке айтема через атрибут `android:onClick` - данный способ действует только в активити и не действует в фрагментах. Другие способы [обработать клик](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/423291/177345) в `RecyclerView`*

Разметка айтема:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="8dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/buttonFavorite"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="Station" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonFavorite"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="onClickFavorite"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="Add favorite" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Весь проект [на github](https://github.com/pavlofff/FavoriteObjectbox)

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72290/discussion-on-answer-by-pavlofff--------).