# Пропадают станции из Избранного после выхода из приложения

Tags: java, android, массивы, arraylist

В моем android приложении можно прослушивать радиостанции. Также присутствует возможность добавлять понравившиеся радиостанции в "Избранное".

Пользователи жалуются, что после того как они добавили станцию в Избранное, она там отобразилась., но после выхода из приложения, если снова открыть его, то список пуст. Проблема возникает не на всех устройствах, и на разных версиях ОС, как отследить причину очистки избранного?

**Сохраняю избранные в файл, в папку с приложением. Сохранение производится с помощью  этого класса (Sack):**

```
public class Sack<T> {

public enum Status {
    SUCCESS,
    ERROR
}

public interface Listener<T> {
    void onResult(Sack.Status status, T obj);
}

private final Class<T> mClass;
private final File mPath;

private final Gson mGson = new Gson();

Sack(final Class<T> klass, final File path) {
    mClass = klass;
    mPath = path;
}

public Pair<Sack.Status, T> doLoad() {

    final AtomicFile file = new AtomicFile(mPath);
    try {
        final FileInputStream in = file.openRead();
        final String s = slurp(new BufferedInputStream(new GZIPInputStream(in)), 4096);
        final Pair<Sack.Status, T> rv = new Pair<>(Sack.Status.SUCCESS, mGson.fromJson(s, mClass));
        in.close();
        return rv;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return new Pair<Sack.Status, T>(Sack.Status.ERROR, null);
    } finally {
    }
}

public static String slurp(final InputStream is, final int bufferSize) {
    final char[] buffer = new char[bufferSize];
    final StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        Reader in = new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8");
        for (; ; ) {
            int rsz = in.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
            if (rsz < 0)
                break;
            out.append(buffer, 0, rsz);
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        return null;
    }
    return out.toString();
}

public AsyncTask<Void, Void, Pair<Sack.Status, T>> load(final Sack.Listener<T> listener) {

    @SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
    final AsyncTask<Void, Void, Pair<Sack.Status, T>> task = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Pair<Sack.Status, T>>() {

        @Override
        protected Pair<Sack.Status, T> doInBackground(final Void... params) {
            return doLoad();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(final Pair<Sack.Status, T> t) {
            if (listener != null)
                listener.onResult(t.first, t.second);
        }
    };

    task.execute();

    return task;
}

public AsyncTask<Void, Void, Pair<Sack.Status, T>> load() {
    return load(null);
}

public Pair<Sack.Status, T> doCommit(final T obj) {
    final AtomicFile file = new AtomicFile(mPath);
    FileOutputStream str = null;
    try {
        str = file.startWrite();
        final BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(new GZIPOutputStream(str));
        out.write(mGson.toJson(obj).getBytes());
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        str.flush();
        str.close();
        file.finishWrite(str);
        return new Pair<Sack.Status, T>(Sack.Status.SUCCESS, obj);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        if (str != null)
            file.failWrite(str);
        return new Pair<Sack.Status, T>(Sack.Status.ERROR, null);
    }
}

public AsyncTask<T, Void, Pair<Sack.Status, T>> commit(final T obj, final Sack.Listener<T> listener) {

    @SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak") final AsyncTask<T, Void, Pair<Sack.Status, T>> task = new AsyncTask<T, Void, Pair<Sack.Status, T>>() {

        @Override
        protected Pair<Sack.Status, T> doInBackground(final T... params) {
            return doCommit(params[0]);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(final Pair<Sack.Status, T> t) {
            if (listener != null)
                listener.onResult(t.first, t.second);
        }
    };

    task.execute(obj);

    return task;
}

public AsyncTask<T, Void, Pair<Sack.Status, T>> commit(final T obj) {
    return commit(obj, null);
}

public static <T> Sack<T> open(final Class<T> entity, final File path) {
    return new Sack<T>(entity, path);
} 
}
```

**Класс (коллекция), который отвечает за добавление, проверку и удаление данных из Избранного:**

```
public class Favorites {

public static ArrayList<String> favoriteUrls = null;
private static File getFavoritesPath() {
    return new File(CacheManager.getRoot(), "favorites");
}

public static void load() {
    try {
        Sack.open(String[].class, getFavoritesPath()).load(new Sack.Listener<String[]>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(final Sack.Status status, final String[] favorites) {
                favoriteUrls = new ArrayList<>();
                if (favorites == null)
                    return;
                favoriteUrls.addAll(Arrays.asList(favorites));
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static List<Station> getFavorites() {
    final List<Station> favorites = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String url : favoriteUrls)
        favorites.add(ArrayListMain.getStation(url));
    Station.sort(favorites);
    return favorites;
}

public static void addFavorite(final String favoriteUrl) {
    if (!favoriteUrls.contains(favoriteUrl)) {
        favoriteUrls.add(favoriteUrl);
        commit();
    }
}

public static void removeFavorite(final String favoriteUrl) {
    if (favoriteUrls.contains(favoriteUrl)) {
        favoriteUrls.remove(favoriteUrl);
        commit();
    }
}

private static void commit() {
    final String[] urls = favoriteUrls.toArray(new String[favoriteUrls.size()]);
    Sack.open(String[].class, getFavoritesPath()).commit(urls);
}
```

}

У меня две коллекции. одна это весь список станций, а другая, как раз вот этот представленный класс Favorites (избранное).

Добавляю в избранное из активити, с помощью статического метода  `addFavorite`, которому на вход подаю нужную строку с данными станции. Не понимаю, почему на некоторых устройствах добавляются станции, отображаются как положено в избранном, но при выходе с приложения и повторном открытии, избранное пустое.

На моем устройстве (samsung galaxy s6 edge) ошибок в логах (смотрю в logcat при отладке) никаких не возникает, что при проверке, что при добавлении/удалении из коллекции избранного. С чем пропажа станций может быть связана?

**P.S:** чистильщики системы (cleaner'ы), или ручная очистка кеша приложения не связана именно с тем, что в итоге станции исчезают сами. Есть какие нибудь идеи или предложения? буду очень раз выслушать. Если нужны какие либо еще данные, мол откуда берутся станции, через что выводятся и т.д - обязательно поделюсь информацией.

Comment: В общем о я вам уже [давал идею и предложение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/771965/177345) которая соответствует архитектуре подобных приложений и которая будет работать, но вы видимо решили продолжать свой собственный велосипед изобретать и теперь не понимаете, почему он местами не едет :(.

Comment: @pavlofff, при чем тут велосипед, если это сделали до меня, и это рабочая система. Я понимаю что ваша идея лучше, и производительнее. Но я не смог заставить её работать. У меня не получилось подвязать имеющуюся коллекцию (добавить все объекты из json файла в ObjectBox. Не смог с ней разобраться((