# Добавить элемент в корзину при нажатии. Android

Tags: java, android

Есть `activity` с товарами ,

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При нажатии на кнопку `в корзину` надо добавить товар в корзину, то есть на другое `activity`, и, соответственно в другой форме. Основная сложность в формировании и отправки объекта на другое `activity`. Буду признателен за советы.

Comment: А вы уверены что при добавлении нужно переходить сразу в корзину?

Comment: такие вещи никогда не делаются "передачей объекта" пототму что вся такая архитектура будет "висеть в воздухе" и рухнет при любой возможности. такие вещи [делаются через БД](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/559151/177345). каждая активити делает свои запросы в общюю БД и ничего не передают между друг другом, тем более содержимое корзины. Пример [реализации избранного через БД](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/771965/177345) (та же корзина по факту)

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете использовать следующий код, для отправки объекта в другое **activity**:

```
Order myOrder = new Order();
Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(myOrder);
startActivity(intent);
```

где класс `Order` должен расширять `Parcelable`

P.S. Я не уверен, что переход сразу в корзину - это хорошое решение!