# Сохранение состояния кнопки в RecyclerView после выхода из Activity

Tags: android, recyclerview, button, recyclerview.adapter, android-button

Есть список продуктов `RecyclerView`. Возле каждого продукта есть кнопка(+), при нажатии на которую продукт добавляется в корзину и кнопка меняет свой вид(х). Как сделать, чтобы сохранялось состояние кнопки, когда человек добавил продукт, кнопка изменилась (появился крестик) потом вышел из `activity`, вернулся обратно, а кнопки сохранили свое состояние(т.е. возле продуктов, который человек выбрал, крестики так и остались)?

Comment: Хранить состояние кнопок и прочего в базе например.

Comment: вам нужно хранить данные в хранилище, [не зависящем от состояния активити](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/539153/177345). В случае с какими то продуктами идеально подойдет база данных в которую и будут записываться все состояния по каждому продукту. Затем, при чтении данных, по ним востанавливается текущее состояние  Сейчас модно использовать решение от Google - Room. Пример [реализации избранного](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/771965/177345) на основе ORM ObjectBox (кстати самая быстрая ORM из доступных для андроид), но вы можете использовать любое удобное вам хранилище