# Как управлять состоянием адаптера из другого адаптера?

Tags: java, android, adapter, recyclerview.adapter

Есть фрагмент со списоком с адаптером. Я вставляю фрагмент несколько раз в активность. Мне нужно при нажатии на элемент в одном адаптере - обновлять данные в другом. Как это реализовать? Класс адаптера один и тот же.

**RecyclerStationAdapter.class**

```
public class RecyclerStationAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerStationAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;
private List<Station> mStations;
private Context mContext;
private Radio mRadio;

private ArrayList<ViewHolder> viewHolders = new ArrayList<>();

PreferenceHelper preferenceHelper;

public RecyclerStationAdapter(Context context, Radio radio) {
    this.mStations = radio.getStations();
    this.mRadio = radio;
    this.mLayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    mContext = context;
    preferenceHelper = new PreferenceHelper(mContext);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.example_list_item_station, parent, false);
    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);

    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    Station station = mStations.get(position);
    holder.textView.setText(station.getName());

    Glide.with(mContext)
            .asBitmap()
            .load(station.getImage())
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.AUTOMATIC)
            .into(new CustomTarget<Bitmap>() {
                @Override
                public void onResourceReady(@NonNull Bitmap resource, @Nullable Transition<? super Bitmap> transition) {
                    RadioStationController.setHashMap(station, resource);
                    holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(resource);
                }

                @Override
                public void onLoadCleared(@Nullable Drawable placeholder) {

                }
            });

    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            createFirebaseReport(position);
            //Toaster.Toast(mContext, "Adapter.holder.onClick: " + mStations.get(position).getName());

            ReportHelper.report(mStations.get(position));
            AnimatorHelper.viewHolders = viewHolders;

            RadioStationController.setSelectedRadio(mRadio);

            if (RadioStationController.getSelectedStation() != null && RadioStationController.getSelectedStation() == mStations.get(position) && PlayerService.isPlaying) {
                MediaControllerHelper.mediaController.getTransportControls().pause();
                AnimatorHelper.stopAnimation(holder.playViewAnimation);
            } else {

                if (PlayerService.isPlaying) {
                    MediaControllerHelper.mediaController.getTransportControls().pause();
                }
                if (MediaControllerHelper.mediaController != null) {
                    MediaControllerHelper.mediaController.getTransportControls().play();
                }
                AnimatorHelper.startAnimation(holder.playViewAnimation);
            }
            RadioStationController.setSelectedStation(mStations.get(position));
            if ((holder.imageView.getDrawable()) != null)
                RadioStationController.setImageSelectedStation(RadioStationController.getBitmapFromhashmap(station));
        }
    });
    holder.itemView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            KeyboardHelper.closeKeyboard(mContext, holder.itemView);
            return false;
        }
    });

    holder.itemView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            if (mRadio.getGenre().equals("Избранное") | preferenceHelper.checkContainsStation(station)) {
                preferenceHelper.deleteFavoriteStation(station);
                mStations = preferenceHelper.getFavoriteListStations();
                notifyItemRemoved(position);
                notifyItemRangeChanged(position, mStations.size());
                Toaster.Toast(mContext, "RecyclerStationAdapter.OnLongClickListener.DELETE_FROM_"+mRadio.getGenre().toUpperCase());

            } else {
                preferenceHelper.addFavoriteStation(station);
                Toaster.Toast(mContext, "RecyclerStationAdapter.OnLongClickListener.ADD_TO_"+mRadio.getGenre().toUpperCase());

            }
            notifyDataSetChanged();
            return false;
        }
    });
    viewHolders.add(holder);
    if (RadioStationController.getSelectedStation() != null && checkEqualsStation(station, RadioStationController.getSelectedStation()) && PlayerService.isPlaying)
        AnimatorHelper.startAnimation(holder.playViewAnimation);
}

private boolean checkEqualsStation(Station station, Station selectedStation) {
    return station.getStream().equals(selectedStation.getStream());
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

private void createFirebaseReport(int position) {
    try {
        FirebaseAnalytics firebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(mContext);
        Bundle eventDetails = new Bundle();

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(mStations.get(position).getName() + " : " + mStations.get(position).getStream());

        eventDetails.putString("station", sb.toString());
        firebaseAnalytics.logEvent("select_station", eventDetails);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("glide", e.getMessage());
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mStations.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements Serializable {
    final ImageView imageView;
    final TextView textView;
    public final AVLoadingIndicatorView playViewAnimation;

    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivStation);
        textView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvStation);
        playViewAnimation = itemView.findViewById(R.id.playing_anim);
    }
}
}
```

**StationsFragment.class**

```
public class StationsFragment extends Fragment {

private Radio mRadio;

private Context mContext;

public RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private RecyclerStationAdapter mRecyclerStationAdapter;

public StationsFragment(Context context, Radio radio) {
    mRadio = radio;
    mContext = context;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_stations, container, false);

    mRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    mRecyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
    mRecyclerStationAdapter = new RecyclerStationAdapter(mContext, mRadio);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mRecyclerStationAdapter);

    return view;
}
}
```

**MainActivity.class**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private LinearLayout mLinearLayout;
private PreferenceHelper preferenceHelper;

private FirebaseAnalytics mFirebaseAnalytics;

static {
    AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
}



@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    MediaControllerHelper.mediaController.getTransportControls().stop();
    unbindService(MediaControllerHelper.serviceConnection);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    CreateNotificationChannel.create(this);

    preferenceHelper = new PreferenceHelper(this);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        // Set the local night mode to some value
        AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(
                AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
    }

    MediaControllerHelper.onCreate(this);

    bindService(new Intent(this, PlayerService.class), MediaControllerHelper.serviceConnection, BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

    mLinearLayout = findViewById(R.id.main_container);
    mFirebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
    }

    ArrayList<Radio> radioArray = (ArrayList<Radio>) JSONHelper.importFromJSON(getApplicationContext());
    radioArray.add(0, preferenceHelper.getRadio());
    RadioStationController.setListRadios(radioArray);

    SearchFragment searchFragment = new SearchFragment(radioArray, mLinearLayout);
    FragmentTransaction mFragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    mFragmentTransaction.add(R.id.container_from_toolbar, searchFragment).commit();

    initialyzeAppMetrica(radioArray);

    createListStations(radioArray);
}

private void initialyzeAppMetrica(ArrayList<Radio> radioArray) {
    ReportHelper.setRadioList(radioArray);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {

    TinyDB tinydb = new TinyDB(this);

    ArrayList<Object> holderObjects = tinydb.getListObject("HOLDER", RecyclerStationAdapter.ViewHolder.class);
    if (AnimatorHelper.viewHolders == null)
        AnimatorHelper.viewHolders = new ArrayList<>();

    for(Object o : holderObjects)
        AnimatorHelper.viewHolders.add((RecyclerStationAdapter.ViewHolder) o);


    tinydb.putInt("POSITION", RadioStationController.getPosition());

    super.onPause();
}

private void createListStations(ArrayList<Radio> radioArray) {

    if (radioArray != null) {

        preferenceHelper.addFavoriteStation(radioArray.get(1).getStations().get(0));//test fav

        for (Radio r : radioArray) {
           /* for (Station station : r.getStations()){
                Glide.with(this).asBitmap().load(station.getImage()).into(new CustomTarget<Bitmap>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResourceReady(@NonNull Bitmap resource, @Nullable Transition<? super Bitmap> transition) {
                        RadioStationController.setHashMap(station, resource);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onLoadCleared(@Nullable Drawable placeholder) {

                    }
                });
            }*/
            RadioStationController.getListStations().addAll(r.getStations());

            StationsFragment stationsFragment = new StationsFragment(this, r);

            inflateContainers(stationsFragment, r.getGenre(), r.getStations().size());

        }
    }
}

private void inflateContainers(Fragment fragment, String textGenre, int textCount){
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(this.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View childLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_child_conteiner, mLinearLayout, false);

    ImageView imageView = childLayout.findViewById(R.id.child_container_imageview_arrow);

    FragmentManager mFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction mFragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();

    ExpandableLayout expandableLayout = childLayout.findViewById(R.id.child_container_expandableLayout);
    expandableLayout.setId(View.generateViewId());
    expandableLayout.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());

    LinearLayout linearLayout = childLayout.findViewById(R.id.child_container_main_container);
    linearLayout.setId(LinearLayout.generateViewId());
    linearLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (expandableLayout.isExpanded()) {
                AnimationRotate.RotateArrow(imageView, expandableLayout.isExpanded());
                expandableLayout.toggle();
            } else {
                AnimationRotate.RotateArrow(imageView, expandableLayout.isExpanded());
                expandableLayout.expand();

            }
            KeyboardHelper.closeKeyboard(getApplicationContext(), v);
        }
    });

    LinearLayout linearLayoutContainer = childLayout.findViewById(R.id.child_container_container);
    linearLayoutContainer.setId(LinearLayout.generateViewId());

    TextView textViewGenre = childLayout.findViewById(R.id.child_container_textview_genre);
    textViewGenre.setId(View.generateViewId());
    textViewGenre.setText(textGenre);

    TextView textViewCountStations = childLayout.findViewById(R.id.child_container_textview_count_stations);
    textViewCountStations.setId(View.generateViewId());
    textViewCountStations.setText(String.valueOf(textCount));

    mFragmentTransaction.add(linearLayoutContainer.getId(), fragment, textGenre).commit();
    mLinearLayout.addView(linearLayout);

    expandableLayout.toggle();
    if (!expandableLayout.isExpanded())
        imageView.setRotation(Const.CURRENT_ROTATE_ARROW);

}
}
```

Comment: Хотелось бы некоторого пояснения фразы "вставляю фрагмент несколько раз". Как это выглядит и зачем так делать?

Comment: Могли бы вы показать код

Comment: Обновил содержание.

Comment: При OnLongClick в адаптере я хочу добавить элемент в другой адаптер, если его там еще нету.

Comment: как правильно [организовать избранное](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/771965/177345), то есть проблема решается не перекладыванием данных между отображениями, а маркером в этих данных и соответствующими запросами

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вы хотите изменить List mStations при каких то действиях, если да то добавьте метод setData(List stations) в ваш RecyclerStationAdapter.class

```
void setData(List<Station> stations) {
            this.mStations = stations;
            notifyDataSetChanged(); // обновляет список 
}
```

и вызывайте его с новым List station

```
mRecyclerStationAdapter.setData(mStations); // новые данные
```

Comment: Тогда получается, что мне нужно при инициализации StationsFragment в createListStations (MainActivity) сохранять mRecyclerStationAdapter в статическое поле, затем из адаптера, в котором происходит долгое нажатие, уже вызывать его обновление. Так?

Comment: можно так как вы сказали, можно вызывать прямо из адаптера setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {...}); если вам известны данные нового списка.

Comment: Понимаете, у меня несколько списков с текущим адаптером и в них разные List<Station>. Я не могу вызвать из этого адаптера метод обновления для другого адаптера... А делать так, как я описал - здесь может быть утечка памяти.

Comment: весьма изощренная реализация, может вам следует упросить ее, разделив на части

Comment: У меня не богатый опыт в программировании. Как бы вы это упростили?

Comment: отделить ту часть которая может изменятся от той которая изменятся не будет, как вариант написать еще один адаптер для того списка который может изменятся

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104993/discussion-between-student158-and-igo).