# android - первый элемент RecyclerView не нажимается

Tags: java, android, xml

У меня `RecylerView`, которая должна реагировать на нажатия.
Для простоты задаю два текста в качестве элемента.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:background="#ABCDEF">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewHeader"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Header"
        android:textSize="18dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewContent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textViewHeader"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Content" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Это адаптер с обработчиком нажатия. Задал обработчик в методе `onCreateViewHolder`.

```
public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private String[][] dataset;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private View.OnClickListener onClickListener;

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView textViewHeader;
        public TextView textViewContent;

        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            textViewHeader = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textViewHeader);
            textViewContent = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textViewContent);
        }
    }

    public RecyclerAdapter(Context context, String[][] dataset, RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        this.context = context;
        this.dataset = dataset;
        this.recyclerView = recyclerView;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycler_item, parent, false);
        v.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
        onClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int itemPosition = recyclerView.getChildPosition(v);
                String item = dataset[itemPosition][0];
                Toast.makeText(context, item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                String[][] dataset0 = dataset;
                dataset0[itemPosition][0] = dataset0[itemPosition][0] + " (clicked)";
                recyclerView.setAdapter(new RecyclerAdapter(context, dataset0, recyclerView));
            }
        };
        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.textViewHeader.setText(dataset[position][0]);
        holder.textViewContent.setText(dataset[position][1]);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return dataset.length;
    }
}
```

В активити один `RecyclerView`

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
```

В коде активити только даю определение списка и задаю адаптер.

```
    RecyclerView recyclerView;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recView);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
            recyclerView.setAdapter(new RecyclerAdapter(this, new String[][]{{"A", "B"}, 
                {"C", "D"}, {"E", "F"}, {"G", "H"}}, recyclerView));
        }
```

Когда нажимаю на элементы, обработчик не действует на первый элемент. При нажатии на остальные элементы получаю всплывающее сообщение и изменение в тексте. Как это исправить?

Comment: а что за адская конструкция с изменением адаптера? чтобы обновить данные у адаптера есть метод `notifyDataSetChanged()`. Слушатель кликов можно [повешать во многих местах](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/423291/177345), но в `onGreateViewHolder()` - в последнюю очередь (так не надо делать вообще)

Comment: вам нужно сделать, чтобы при нажатии на айтем списка к тексту добавлялось "clicked"?

Comment: Да, и чтобы увидел всплывающее сообщение. Обработчик действует на все элементы кроме первого.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это один из тех случаев, когда проще написать правильно, чем разбираться, что не так, потому что вы используете абсолютно неверное решение. Ваш код будет создавать большое количество совершенно ненужных объектов и у меня нет никакого желания профилировать этот код, но есть большая вероятность утечки памяти, не говоря уже о том, что он полностью не соответствует принятым паттернам и архитектуре Android в частности и ООП в целом.

Предлагаю следующий адаптер, который лишен всех проблем адаптера в вашем вопросе:

```
public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.Holder> {

    private final Context context;
    private final String[][] dataset;

    RecyclerAdapter(Context context, String[][] dataset) {
        this.context = context;
        this.dataset = dataset;
    }

    @Override
    public Holder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycler_item, parent, false);
        return new Holder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final Holder holder, int position) {
        holder.textViewHeader.setText(dataset[position][0]);
        holder.textViewContent.setText(dataset[position][1]);
        holder.item.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                clicked(holder.getAdapterPosition());
            }
        });

    }

    private void clicked(int position) {
        Toast.makeText(context, dataset[position][0], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        dataset[position][0] += " (clicked)";
        notifyItemChanged(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return dataset.length;
    }

    static class Holder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        final TextView textViewHeader;
        final TextView textViewContent;
        final LinearLayout item;

        Holder(View view) {
            super(view);
            item = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.item); //ID корневого лэйаута в айтеме
            textViewHeader = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewHeader);
            textViewContent = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewContent);
        }
    }
}
```

Активити:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recView);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(new RecyclerAdapter(this, new String[][]{{"A", "B"}, {"C", "D"}, {"E", "F"}, {"G", "H"}}));
    }
}
```

и немного рефакторинга в разметке, это позволит несколько поберечь ресурсы устройства:

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</FrameLayout>
```

recycler_item.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/item"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:background="#ABCDEF"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewHeader"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        tools:text="Header" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewContent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        tools:text="Content" />
</LinearLayout>
```