# Реализация "списка" с использованием RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, recyclerview, recyclerviewadapter

Как можно, используя RecyclerView, сделать список такого типа?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
При этом все данные должны считываться с файла(это я могу сам).
Главная загвоздка в том, что я не особо понимаю, как можно добавлять в массиве новые строки. И как реализовать нажатие на кнопку и соответственный выбор дальнейшего действия.
Прошу помочь если не кодом, то хотя бы советом/ссылкой на нечто подобное.

Comment: Вопрос может содержать только одну проблему. Как добавить нажатие на кнопку смотрите [этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/423291/177345). По второй проблеме (как добавлять новые строки) вам нужно создать новый вопрос, куда приложить код того, что уже сделано и более подробное описание проблемы, потому что в таком виде может быть множество вариантов и угадывать, что нужно именно вам никому не интересно.