# Ошибка java.lang.NullPointerException при нажатии на элемента RecyclerView из Фрагмента

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Вопросов с похожими проблемами не нашел и поэтому решил задать свой. Не могу ловить клик на элемент `RecyclerView` из Фрагмента. У меня есть `Fragment` который показывает данные в виде списка. Этот список создается с помощью RecyclerView. Мне нужно чтобы при нажатии на элемента открыть другое активити. Но при нажатии я получаю вот это:

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.app.demo.ItemClickListener.onItemClick(android.view.View, int)' on a null object reference
```

Мой интерфейс `ItemClickListener`:

```
public interface ItemClickListener {
    void onItemClick(View view, int position);
}
```

Код на `ContactsFragment` для реакции на клик который не выполняется:

```
 @Override
    public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "It works!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Код на адаптере `RecyclerView` на которого указывает стектрейс:

```
  @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ContactsAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {


      holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
             listener.onItemClick(v,position);
         }
     });
```

Стектрейс говорит что ошибка это здесь :  `listener.onItemClick(v,position);`
Если убрать эту строку и например добавить туда `Toast` тогда никаких ошибок не возникает и при нажатии на элемент этот `Toast` показывается.
Мне нужно знать как решить эту проблему?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Что такое Null Pointer Exception и как его исправить?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/511085/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-null-pointer-exception-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c)

Comment: Это весь код, связанный с интерфейсом слушателя? Если да, то смотрите, как нужно реализовать правильно в [этом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/423291/177345). Сейчас вы получаете NPE потому что у вас нет инициализированного экземпляра объекта listener (он нигде не получает нужное для работы интерфейса значение), в частности видимо отсутствует\не вызывался сеттер интерфейса в активити.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Понял что мой способ получении клика от `RecyclerView` работает для активити но не для фрагментов. Изменил код с помощью [этой](https://android.jlelse.eu/click-listener-for-recyclerview-adapter-2d17a6f6f6c9) статьи и проблема решилась.

Код ViewHolder'a из адаптера для `RecyclerView` :

```
     public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
            private ItemClickListener mListener;

            ViewHolder(View v, ItemClickListener listener) {
                super(v);

                mListener = listener;
                v.setOnClickListener(this);
            }

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               mListener.onItemClick(v, getAdapterPosition());
            }
        }
  public MyAdapter(List<Contact> myList,ItemClickListener listener) {
        this.myList = myList;
             mListener = listener;
    }
    @Override
    public MyAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.my_row,parent,false);

        return new ViewHolder(view,mListener);
    }
```

Код из фрагмента на котором находится `RecyclerView` из которого нужно ловить клики(Этот код находится на `onCreateView`):

```
ItemClickListener listener = new ItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "It works!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
};

mAdapter = new ContactsAdapter(contacts,listener);
recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```