# RecyclerView onClickListener

Tags: java, android

Можно ли в RecyclerView прослушать нажатия и как это сделать , если образец layout
повторяется несколько раз.

Comment: можно. что у вас не получается?

Comment: @michael_best я просто не знаю как это сделать реализовать

Comment: Как вариант [вот тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24471109/recyclerview-onclick) есть примеры.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/423291/177345

Comment: Вот здесь есть прекрасное описание как это сделать православно. https://antonioleiva.com/recyclerview-listener/

Comment: @СергейБувака там по-протестански )

Comment: @Alexander Chernin. Ну для андроид разработчика надо знать английский хотя бы на техническом уровне. На худой конец и Гугл переводчик сгодится. Ну и там по коду можно понять что делать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете создать свой интерфейс например:

```
public interface OnItemClickListener {
    void onItemClick(ContentItem item);
}
```

Конструктор получит объект, который реализует этот интерфейс, вместе с элементами, которые будут отображаться:

```
private final List<ContentItem> items;
private final OnItemClickListener listener;

public ContentAdapter(List<ContentItem> items, OnItemClickListener listener) {
    this.items = items;
    this.listener = listener;
}
```

В качестве альтернативы вы можете создать setOnItemClickListener метод и назначить его таким образом. Теперь, в получите конструктора в пользовательском методе:onBindViewHolder

```
@Override 
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.bind(items.get(position), listener);
}
```

Вот так выглядит bind метод

```
public void bind(final ContentItem item, final OnItemClickListener listener) {
    ...
    itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override public void onClick(View v) {
            listener.onItemClick(item);
        }
    });
}
```

Используйте его всякий раз, когда вам это нужно, создав новый адаптер и прослушиватель, который будет реализовывать поведение при нажатии на элемент. Простой пример:

```
recycler.setAdapter(new ContentAdapter(items, new ContentAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override public void onItemClick(ContentItem item) {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Item Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}));
```